# GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT

Tags: mysql, group-by

veo que desde no se que versión de MySQL el group by obliga a meter todos los campos del select. (esto es configurable, pero no tengo opción de cambiarlo). No entiendo el porqué hay que poner todos los campos del select en el group by, si yo sólo quiero agrupar por el id de usuario por ejemplo.

Si alguien es tan amable de explicar (para tontos, con manzanas) el porqué de esto, se lo agradecería eternamente... estoy mirando por internet, y no entiendo las razones que dan. Dicen que son buenas prácticas, pero hasta hace nada se podía hacer sin problemas y ahora... :(

Comment: no se por que, pero no es todos los campos del select, son todos los campos del from

Comment: @LPZadkiel del select.

Comment: en realidad, son los campos que agregas al select que se sacan del from, las agregaciones por ejemplo no se usan

Comment: Solamente aquellos del select que no usas en funciones de agregación. Mira mi respuesta. @LPZadkiel

Comment: Te felicito por no quedarte con el dogma a ciegas; la explicación de "por qué no" vendrá fácil, pero te invito a que no te quedes ahí y busques el **"por qué sí"** lo cual no se explica tan facilmente con peras y manzanas. Esa característica de MySQL es una optimización, que créeme, sabiendo aprovecharla se vuelve **INDISPENSABLE**.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Es porque en realidad, mysql lo hacia [mal de entrada](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Las clausulas `group by`, en lo que se llama ANSI SQL (o sea sql standard, que es igual para todas las bases), deben si o si, tener todos los campos que están en el `select` y que no se usan en una función de agrupación, definidos en el `group by` para saber como se tiene que agrupar, en que orden. El orden de agrupación, lo da el `group by`, no el `select`.

El problema de no poner algunos campos en el `group by`, es: ¿Cómo sabe la base de datos, cuál de todos los datos que tiene en su base de datos, tiene que poner en ese campo?

Veámoslo con un ejemplo.

Dada una tabla

```
campo1 | categoria | nombrecategoria| monto
1        1           a                100
2        1           a                200
3        1           a                300
4        2           b                400
5        2           b                500
```

Vamos a suponer que queremos obtener las ventas por categoria.

```
select categoria, nombrecategoria, sum(monto)
from tabla
group by categoria
```

Este query, es perfectamente válido en mysql (y como nota al margen, en ACCESS también), y nos da como resultado:

```
categoria | nombrecategoria| monto
1           a                600
2           b                900
```

Sin embargo, ¿qué va a poner en nombre de categoría? ¿cuál de todos los datos en las filas pone?

Nadie puede asegurar que dato va ahí... En este caso nombrecategoria tiene en todas las filas lo mismo. Pero que paso, si con el tiempo la categoría cambio de nombre, ¿pero no de codigo? ¿Cuál es la que va a traer?

Veámoslo de otra forma.. vamos a "romper" la tabla de arriba:

```
campo1 | categoria | nombrecategoria| monto
1        1           a                100
2        1           a                200
3        1           d                300
4        2           b                400
5        2           b                500
```

y ejecutemos el mismo `select`

```
select categoria, nombrecategoria, sum(monto)
from tabla
group by categoria
```

Y ahora.. ¿cómo sería el resultado?

```
categoria | nombrecategoria| monto
1           a                600
2           b                900
```

O el que sigue?

```
categoria | nombrecategoria| monto
1           d                600
2           b                900
```

Los dos resultados son correctos. Y es por eso que la base de datos no puede suponer que queres poner en nombrecategoria, y por eso, todos los campos deben estar en el `group by`, o ser parte de una funcion de agregación.

Como nota, una función de agregación es aquella que analiza los campos, y devuelve un resultado de ellos (suma, cuenta, promedia, etc.)

Comment: Muchas gracias gbianchi, me ha quedado bastante claro. La historia es que a nosotros nos da igual si me sale a y b o d y b, en las consultas en las que estamos usando el group by, ya que simplemente queremos listados y no mostramos ese a y b, o d y b, pero necesitamos previamente para poder saber uno de esos valores... En fin, seguramente tengamos que retocar los group by, y con esto me has explicado bastante bien lo que ocurre...
Gracias!!!!

Comment: @Marta es que si te da igual, entonces ese campo no lo necesitas, y lo podes sacar del select. Te puedo asegurar que cuando no te da igual, te das cuenta lo importante que es que pertenezca al group by.

Comment: _"MySQL lo hacía mal de entrada"_ es una sentencia inquietante.
Podría ser una opinión; a los ojos de los desarrolladores de MySQL los equivocados son los otros.
Alguien que no sepa que es una dependencia funcional debería tener habilitado el modo SQL ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY.
Si dominas el concepto y lo aplicas al diseño de tu base de datos puedes deshabilitarlo y obtener un mejor desempeño y escalabilidad con menos código.

Comment: @Sal desconozco al respecto de como puede ser que no escribiendo el group by completo se obtenga mejor desempeñó o escalabilidad por escribir 3 campos menos en una query....

Comment: Mas columnas, mas trabajo (agrupaciones y ordenamientos) en determinadas situaciones innecesario.

Comment: @Sal me gustaria ver un explain plan que demostrara eso...

Comment: @Sal falso. Eso que hacía MySQL iba en contra de ANSI SQL y estaba implementado en todos los demás motores. MySQL era poco estricto con un montón de cosas y con el tiempo lo fueron normalizando... si hacer las cosas BIEN es más trabajo, pues entonces sí, es más trabajo (pero da resultados predecibles). Lo de innecesario es simplemente querer hacer las cosas rápido. Eso hacían PHP y MySQL hace diez años y por eso les tocó ajustarse a los tiempos modernos.

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿Hacía? ¿Quitaron la detección de dependencia funcional de MySQL?. Ese *"mas trabajo"* puede evitar la [optimización por dependencia](https://hpi.de/fileadmin/user_upload/fachgebiete/naumann/publications/PDFs/2021_kossmann_data.pdf).

Comment: @Sal Segunro. *The data is implicitly grouped already [23]. Hence, both sort- and hash-based aggregation implementations can omit the grouping phase*. Si el optimizador de MySQL no es capaz de asegurar eso, no debía permitirlo :) Es bien interesante pero no es para los comentarios de una pregunta sino para el [chat] Gracias por el enlace!