# ¿Como creo una consulta que me retorne una agrupacion de valores de acuerdo a un campo y que me obtenga todos los datos de la tabla agrupados?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que me obtenga todos los registros que en el campo LLaveRecursivaPadre tengan cierto valor, por ejemplo:
LlaverecursivaPadre tiene valores como 1,2,3,4,5 pero estan repetidos eso quiere decir que varios campos pueden tener el valor 1,2 o 3 etc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero obtener en la consulta es solamente mi ultimo NumberRecord de cada una de las llavesRecursivasPadres diferentes que haya, por ejemplo:
El valor 3 de mi llave recursiva Padre 1, el valor 6 de mi llave Recursiva Padre, el valor 4 de mi llave Recursiva Padre 3 etc.

Pero no solo quiero el valor como tal del campo Number Record sino toda la fila ya que es la que mostrare dentro de mi datatable ya que actualmente mi datatble se ve asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esos tres registros son de llaveRecursivaPadre 1 y solo debería aparecer el ultimo de llaverecursivaPadre 1 para que no se vean los repetidos en la table que le usuario va a ver y solamente los últimos en haberse subido.

> Resumen:

Obtener todas las filas del ultimo NumberRecord de todas las llavesRecursivasPadres diferentes

Lo intente de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT  * FROM tb_uploadexcel where Staus=0 group by LlaveRecursivaPadre
```

Pero me salio el siguiente error:

```
Column 'tb_uploadexcel.idUploadExcel' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, te voy a recomendar leer una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324) que di mas temprano, para que entiendas porque en el group by tienen que ir todos los campos que queres mostrar, si o si.

Despues, lo que estas buscando aca es una agrupación simple, que se hace en dos pasos.

Primero obtenemos solamente el conjunto agrupado:

```
Select LlaveRecursivaPadre, max(NumberRecord) as maximo
from tb_uploadexcel 
where Staus=0 
group by LlaveRecursivaPadre
```

Esta query nos va a devolver un solo registro por LlaveRecursivaPadre y el maximo de NumberRecord.

Con esta query, podemos unirla a la tabla tb_uploadexcel de vuelta, y traer todos los otros campos que necesitas, usando como clave de join justamente estos dos campos de la query que acabamos de armar.

```
select t.* 
from tb_uploadexcel t inner join 
    (Select LlaveRecursivaPadre, max(NumberRecord) as maximo
    from tb_uploadexcel 
    where Staus=0 
    group by LlaveRecursivaPadre) u
    on u.LlaveRecursivaPadre = t.LlaveRecursivaPadre and u.maximo = t.NumberRecord
```

y esta ultima te va a devolver los valores de todos los campos, para los registros que cumplan esa condición.