# Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'bici.servicio.UserId' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy usando:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
},
```

requiero hacer está consulta con eloquent:

```
select `UserId`, count(EstOriId) AS count_start
from `servicio` group by `EstOriId`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando realizar está consulta utilizando Laravel con Eloquent:

```
public function report5()
{
    $data = DB::table('servicio')
        ->select('UserId', DB::raw('count(EstOriId) AS count_start'))
        ->groupBy('EstOriId')
        ->paginate(6);
    return $data;
}
```

Sin embargo me sale esté error al momento de hacer la petición:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'bici.servicio.UserId' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `UserId`,
>   count(EstOriId) AS count_start from `servicio` group by `EstOriId`
>   limit 6 offset 0) ◀"

Ya configure en el config\database.php, como proponen para intentar solucionar este inconveniente:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => false,
        'modes'  => [
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
        ],
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Answer (score 0):

Tú error es que agrupas por la columna calculada así

```
->groupBy('EstOriId')
```

Cuando debería ser por

```
->groupBy('UserId')
```

Por último y como observación, yo te diría que no deshabilites el *modo estricto*  en `config/database.php`

Answer (score 0):

tu problema es debido a la paginación que requieres hacer.

En la documentación de Laravel se indica que `Paginate` no funciona junto a un `GroupBy`

Puedes ver esto aquí: [Enlace](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#basic-usage)

Tambien es necesario modificar la consulta que estas realizando, esta quedaria asi

```
try{ 
   $data = DB::table('servicio')
        ->select(DB::raw("UserId,count(EstOriId) AS count_start"))
        ->groupBy('EstOriId');
    return $data;}
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
        dd($ex->getMessage()); 
        }
```

Te recomiendo utilizar ese `try/catch` mientras programas las consultas en Laravel, ya que así podrás saber lo que esta intentando leer SQL y la consulta la puedes copiar y buscar directamente en tu BD

Answer (score -2):

solo deberias agregar a tu consulta al final un count, por ejemplo:

```
{
    $data = DB::table('servicio') 
      ->select('UserId')
      ->count();
    return $data;
}
```