# Suma de 2 subconsultas con group by MySql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, group-by

Tengo tres tablas: **reservas, clientes_revervas y grupo_familiar**

Y tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT g.nombre ,t.tour, r.cupos, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientes_revervas cr 
WHERE  cr.reserva_id = r.id) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grupo_familiar gp 
WHERE gp.id_cliente_reserva = cr.id) AS reservados, 
          r.fecha_inicial , r.estado,  r.id AS id_reserva FROM `reservas` r
          INNER JOIN tours t ON r.id_evento = t.idTour
          INNER JOIN guias g ON r.id_guia  = g.id
          LEFT JOIN clientes_revervas cr ON cr.reserva_id = r.id
          GROUP BY r.id;
```

La idea es que cuente los clientes referentes una reserva y contar los familiares de dichos clientes, los clientes los cuenta bien, pero los familiares solo cuenta 1 . Para este ejemplo tengo id de reserva **"6"** en la tabla cliente reservas hay 5 clientes con dicho id y en la tabla grupo familiar hay 2 con clientes con **id (44,54)** de la **tabla clientes_reservas** y en grupo familiar hay 3 registros con dichos id (el campo allí se llama `id_cliente_reserva`) hay 1 del id 46 y con el id 44 (estos id son tomados de la **tabla clientes_reservas**), el resultado final es **"7"** cuando debería ser **"8"**

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con este problema?

**Tabla reservas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla clientes_revervas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla grupo_familiar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El principal problema aca es que mysql en sus versiones antiguas, te permite hacer cosas que estan mal (como usar un group by que no incluya a todos los registros de la consulta) y por eso ves cualquier suma. por favor mira este post relacionado  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324 y despues tratemos de arreglar esta consulta, cuando entiendas el problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema con tu consulta es que en la subconsulta en la que obtienes la cantidad de familiares por cliente:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grupo_familiar gp WHERE gp.id_cliente_reserva = cr.id) AS reservados
```

deberías obtener el total de familiares por cliente de la reserva

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grupo_familiar gp, clientes_reservas cr2 
 WHERE gp.id_cliente_reserva = cr2.id and cr2.reserva_id=r.id) as reservados
```

Luego puedes apoyarte en 2 variables (`@cl` y `@fam`) para poder obtener por separado el total de clientes y el total de familiares en 2 columnas y sumarlas en una tercera, de ese modo la consulta podría quedarte por ejemplo de esta forma:

```
SELECT 
@cl:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientes_reservas cr 
 WHERE  cr.reserva_id = r.id) as clientes, 
@fam:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grupo_familiar gp, clientes_reservas cr2 
 WHERE gp.id_cliente_reserva = cr2.id and cr2.reserva_id=r.id) AS familiares,
 @fam+@cl as reservados, 
   r.id AS id_reserva 
      FROM `reservas` r
      LEFT JOIN clientes_reservas cr ON cr.reserva_id = r.id
      GROUP BY r.id;
```

Puedes ver una demostración de como funcionaría la consulta en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d1722/5)</kbd>

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Exacto el problema era en los familiares por cliente, no sabía cómo realizarlo..muchas gracias era justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: @Venté de nada que tengas buen día.