# ¿Necesito una subconsulta para sumar dos columnas en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

No tiene relación la pregunta escrita, o bien si, les comentaré:

Estoy trabajando con una tabla llamada `pasajes_db`, del cual contiene las fecha de viajes y el precio tanto de ida, como de vuelta.

```
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|id|   fecha_compra |estado_solicitud|tarifa_ida | tarifa_vuelta |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|1 |   2019-07-10   |    EMITIDO     | 140       |  130          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|2 |   2019-08-21   |    EMITIDO     | 155       |  140          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|3 |   2019-09-01   |    PERDIDO     | 180       |  160          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|4 |   2019-09-01   |    EMITIDO     | 90        |  110          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|2 |   2019-09-08   |    EMITIDO     | 130       |  120          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|3 |   2019-09-13   |    PERDIDO     | 130       |  130          |
+--+-----+----------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Tengo ingresado los estados de aquellos pasajes, significa que todos son comprados, sin embargo los perdidos se toman como costo ya que cliente nunca usó su pasaje.

Lo que necesito realmente de todo esto **es generar una consulta que realice suma de la tarifa ida y tarifa vuelta al año, y además que me visualice los pasajes emitidos y los perdidos** (emitidos - perdidos).

De momento tengo esto, pero sólo me entrega los emitidos.

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_compra) Mes, SUM(tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta) as total_emitido 
FROM pasajes_db 
WHERE estado_solicitud='EMITIDO' 
GROUP BY Mes
```

**RESULTADO**

```
+-----+----------+----------------+
|   Mes          |  total_emitido |
+-----+----------+----------------+
|   7            |     270        | 
+-----+----------+----------------+
|   8            |     295        | 
+-----+----------+----------------+
|   9            |     450        | 
+-----+----------+----------------+
```

Sé que estoy usando un `WHERE` que sólo está  condicionando los "emitidos", pero no logro  traer la solicitud "perdido", ¿acaso tengo que crear una subconsulta ?

Comment: Emitido y perdido en columnas diferentes o sirve que sean filas?

Comment: perdón, me refiero a que emitido y perdido en columnas diferentes.

Comment: en el resultado se espera obtener la columna mes,  total_emitido, total_perdido.. es decir 3 columnas.
Si notas el resultado que mostré solo faltaría la total_perdido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sé que estoy usando un WHERE que sólo está condicionando los "emitidos", pero no logro traer la solicitud "perdido", tengo que crear ¿ subconsulta ?

En este caso, no es necesario crear una sub-consulta, ya que se puede solucionar utilizando `IF`

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
   MONTH(fecha_compra) Mes, 
   SUM(IF(estado_solicitud = 'EMITIDO', tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta, 0)) as total_emitido,
   SUM(IF(estado_solicitud = 'PERDIDO', tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta, 0)) as total_perdido
FROM pasajes_db 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_compra)
```

Comment: Agradecido de tu respuesta, es más sencilla de lo que pensaba.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a solucionar un problema que tiene este query, porque mysql te permite hacerlo mal
(mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324) para entender porque).

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_compra) Mes, SUM(tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta) as total_emitido 
FROM pasajes_db 
WHERE estado_solicitud='EMITIDO' 
GROUP BY Mes
```

Mes no pertenece a ese query. Mysql te deja hacer algo mágico aca, que es poner Mes (que es una columna que no existe) como condicion de agrupamiento. Y te digo que no existe, porque cualquier otra base de datos te daria error, porque usar el Alias de la columna, es lo ultimo que hace un motor de base de datos. Entoces, tu group by deberia ser

```
Group by MONTH(fecha_compra)
```

Sacando ese problema, para tener dos columnas, vamos a necesitar agregar a la condicion de group el estado..

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_compra) Mes, estado_solicitud, SUM(tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta) as suma
FROM pasajes_db 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_compra), estado_solicitud
```

Y luego de ello, usarlo para generar otra query que agrupe por mes, y ponga segun el estado la suma en una columna o en la otra.

```
Select a.Mes, 
    sum(if(a.estado_solicitud='EMITIDO',a.suma,0)) as suma_emitido,
    sum(if(a.estado_solicitud='PERDIDO',a.suma,0)) as suma_perdido
from (
        SELECT MONTH(fecha_compra) Mes, estado_solicitud, SUM(tarifa_ida+tarifa_vuelta) as suma
        FROM pasajes_db 
        GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_compra), estado_solicitud
    ) as a
group by Mes
```

Aunque esto funcione con subconsultas, creo que si lo pones todo en la consulta superior "podria" funcionar. Pero te dejo la prueba para vos.

Comment: estoy probando tu respuesta final, y me aparece lo siguiente: #1248 - Cada tabla derivada debe tener su propio alias.

Comment: lo solucioné, sólo tuve que añadir un as al final del from () as ...  muchas gracias.

Comment: ciertoooo... mi error.. ya lo agrego... que bueno que te sirvio