# Consulta SQL avanzada

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada **usuario** y otra **dispositivo** con una relación de **1:M**. La lógica funciona de la siguiente forma: cada vez que el usuario realizar un login, en la tabla `dispositivo`se actualiza un atributo `ultima_conexion` **o** se realiza un `insert` si el dispositivo es nuevo. También de agregar que la tabla `dispositivo` posee un `status` que puede ser `ACTIVE`, `INACTIVE` y `WAIT`.

Intento realizar una consulta que traiga el listado de usuario con el dispositivo que hizo conexión mas reciente (sin importa status) y la cantidad de dispositivos para ese usuario con status `WAIT`.

tabla usuario:

```
|id   | nombre  |
| 1   |  AAA    |
| 2   |  BBB    |
| 3   |  CCC    |
| 4   |  DDD    |
```

tabla dispositivo:

```
|id   |  usuario |  ultima_conexion | huella  |  status |
| 1   |     1    |  19-10-12 01:01  |   dis1  |  ACTIVE |
| 2   |     2    |  19-10-01 13:27  |   dis1  |  ACTIVE |
| 3   |     2    |  19-09-15 08:09  |   dis2  |  WAIT   |
| 4   |     2    |  19-09-15 09:10  |   dis1  |  ACTIVE |
| 5   |     2    |  19-10-13 00:05  |   dis3  |  WAIT   |
| 6   |     3    |  19-10-13 02:10  |   dis3  |  ACTIVE |
```

Resultado del Query esperado:

```
| id  |  nombre |  id  |  huella |  ultima_conx | total_espera |
|  1  |   AAA   |  1   |  disp1  |19-10-12 01:01|        NULL  |
|  2  |   BBB   |  5   |  disp3  |19-10-13 00:05|          2   |
|  3  |   CCC   |  6   |  disp3  |19-10-13 02:10|        NULL  |
|  4  |   DDD   | NULL |   NULL  |     NULL     |        NULL  |
```

Itenté realizar esto consulta pero no arroja lo esperado:

```
SELECT
    usuario.id,
    usuario.nombre,
    disp.id,
    disp.huella,
    MAX( disp.ultima_conexion) as ultima_conexion,
    COUNT( disp_wait.device_id ) as total_espera
FROM
    usuario

LEFT JOIN dispositivo disp
    ON disp.usuario= usuario.id

LEFT JOIN dispositivo disp_wait
    ON disp_wait.usuario= usuario.id

WHERE
   disp_wait.status= 'WAIT'

GROUP BY
    disp.id
```

Comment: anda mirando esto mientras te escribo una respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324

Comment: Yo logro consultar el listado de usuario con el dispositivo que hizo ultima conexión, pero cuando intento agregar la consulta con el count() para que cuente la cantidad de dispositivo que tiene ese usuario en WAIT, es donde la consulta se vuelve errónea.

Comment: Con los cambios que hiciste cambiaste todo el sentido de la pregunta y mi respuesta ya no es valida :/.. Tene en cuenta que mi respuesta es sobre la version anterior de tu pregunta.

Comment: Es que la consulta original es mas extensa, esta solo es un resumen. gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de una sub-consulta para obtener el registro *del dispositivo que hizo la conexión mas reciente*

Luego hay un par de cambios:

- `disp_wait.device_id`, en teoria no existe, por lo que lo cambie a `disp_wait.id`
- `GROUP BY disp.id`, estaría mal porque queremos contar los del usuario, por lo que lo cambie por `GROUP BY usu.id`
- `WHERE disp_wait.status= 'WAIT'`, si tienes/creas un índice con ambas columnas, es mejor ponerlo en la condición del `LEFT JOIN`

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
    usu.id,
    usu.nombre,
    disp.id,
    disp.huella,
    disp.ultima_conexion,
    COUNT( disp_wait.id ) as total_espera
FROM usuario usu
LEFT JOIN dispositivo disp
    ON disp.id = (
      SELECT t.id
      FROM dispositivo t
      WHERE t.usuario = usu.id
      ORDER BY t.ultima_conexion DESC
      LIMIT 1
    )

LEFT JOIN dispositivo disp_wait
    ON disp_wait.usuario= usu.id
    AND disp_wait.status= 'WAIT'

GROUP BY
    usu.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56439d/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias, este si arroja los resultados.

Answer (score 2):

ok.. hay dos problemas aca.. primero y principal, el group by tiene que tener todos los campos que estan en el query y no forman parte de una función de agregación (mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324)).

Una vez solucionado esto, puede que esta consulta funcione, pero si no hay que hacer varias cosas para solucionar lo que necesitas:

Primero ubicar el maximo de ultima conexion para cada dispositivo (venias bien ahi):

```
SELECT
    disp.usuario,
    disp.id,
    'ultima conexion' as estado
    MAX( disp.ultima_conexion) as valor
FROM
    dispositivo disp
GROUP BY
    disp.usuario, disp.id, 'ultima conexion'
```

Eso nos devuelve para cada usuario el ultimo dispositivo del que se conecto.

Y a esto, ahora le sumamos con un [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```
**query anterior**
union
SELECT
    disp.usuario,
    disp.id,
    'cantidad en espera' as estado,
    count(disp.id) as valor
FROM
    dispositivo disp
where
    disp_wait.status= 'WAIT'
GROUP BY
    disp.usuario, disp.id, 'cantidad en espera'
```

La cantidad que estan en wait. Esto incluye si esa fue la ultima conexión.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, tengo un problema, en el primer query el valor de la ultima conexión si es el que corresponde en la tabla, pero no esta relacionado con el dispositivo, es decir, que la ultima conexión si corresponde pero no lo asocia al dispositivo.