# Recuperar valores de una columna basandome en el maximo de otra MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vistas

> Tabla

`Pedido | Revisión | Cliente
   1    |    0     |   1
   1    |    0     |   2
   2    |    0     |   1
   1    |    1     |   1
   1    |    1     |   2
   2    |    1     |   1
   1    |    2     |   1
   2    |    0     |   2
   3    |    0     |   1`

> Como debería quedar la vista (se ocultan los datos de revisiones menores a la ultima)

`Pedido | Revisión | Cliente
   1    |    1     |   2
   2    |    1     |   1
   1    |    2     |   1
   2    |    0     |   2
   3    |    0     |   1`

> Ordenada

`Pedido | Revisión | Cliente
   1    |    2     |   1
   2    |    1     |   1
   3    |    0     |   1
   1    |    1     |   2
   2    |    0     |   2`

La tabla con la que trabajo es mucho mas grande y uso una vista que conecta los pedidos con el desglose de los mismos, existe la posibilidad que se revisione algún pedido y se deban editar los datos que hay dentro entonces para identificar el ultimo pedido revisionado debería tomar la revisión mas alta de todos los pedidos pero no estoy hallando el método para obtener esto.

Solo a modo de información pondré las tablas reales y la vista que arme, que lo que hace es traer todos pedidos (que en la tabla real se identifican como listas de despacho) con sus items que hay dentro (desglose de listas de despacho)

> Tabla listas de despacho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tabla desglose de listas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tabla de vista y declaración SELECT.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
select ld.listas_id AS listas_id,
ld.lista_numero AS lista_numero,
ld.revision AS revision,
ld.fecha AS fecha,
ld.proyectista AS proyectista,
desglo_ld.codigo_qr AS codigo_qr,
desglo_ld.codigo AS codigo,
desglo_ld.descripcion AS descripcion,
desglo_ld.cantidad AS cantidad,
desglo_ld.largo AS largo,
desglo_ld.desarrollo AS desarrollo,
desglo_ld.color AS color,
desglo_ld.peso AS peso,
desglo_ld.superficie AS superficie
FROM listas_de_despacho ld
INNER JOIN desgloce_de_ld desglo_ld ON ld.listas_id = desglo_ld.listas_id
```

Como se puede observar las piezas en la revisión 1 tienen valores distintos al primero (también podrían borrarse los códigos o agregarse mas, es una edición a la lista de despacho). Que debo agregar a la declaración para que cumpla mis necesidades ?

> Importante a tener en cuenta
>   La lista_numero y revision de la tabla listas_de_despacho se pueden repetir pero para distintas obra_id.

Ejemplo:

`lista_numero | revision | obra_id
         1    |    0     |    1
         2    |    0     |    1
         1    |    0     |    2
         1    |    1     |    1
         2    |    1     |    1
         1    |    0     |    3`

> Intente

`(SELECT max(listas_id) FROM listas_de_despacho GROUP BY lista_numero)` que devuelve el id unico mas alto de todas las veces que se repite la misma lista de despacho -> Problema, los numeros de listas de despacho se pueden repetir si las obras son distintas.

Comment: Tu primer query es un simple group by pedido, donde buscas max revision. Eso lo intentaste? que problema tuviste con eso?

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta con lo que probe.

Comment: ese query iria bien. Pero no se porque sacas max(listas_id), si vos aclaraste que queres max(revision). proba eso, y volve a aclarar tu problema

Comment: Lo que sucede es que, cada obra tiene lista_numero y cada lista_numero tiene revisión por ende,  lista_numero y revisión se van a repetir lo que no se va a repetir son las obras. con misma lista_numero y misma revisión. entonces no encuentro forma de traer los últimos datos a menos que use listas_id como mi referencia del valor mas alto que tiene una lista_numero (ya que si hay una lista numero con la lista_id mas alta significa que esta tuvo una revision), pero esta ultima logica que nombre se desvanece cuando se agrega una nueva obra porque pueden tener la misma lista_numero y revision.

Comment: Martin, no termino de entender tu problema. porque el ejemplo que diste al principio de tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con lo que escribis despues. y una cosa es resolver el ejemplo de arriba y otra cosa distinta, pareceria lo que decis despues. Te sugiero que revises tu pregunta, pongas un ejemplo claro de tus datos de entrada y los datos que queres como salida y asi vamos a poder encontrar tu query. pero no deja de ser un group by con un max

Comment: Te pido disculpas, ahi corregi el inicio de la pregunta agregando el valor faltante que se debe tener en cuenta.

Comment: es la misma query.. max(revision), max(cliente) y el order que queres... lo probaste?

Comment: Pero si hago eso me trae la máxima rev alcanzada que tuvo algún pedido de cada cliente es decir, si el pedido 1 llego a la rev 10 y el pedido 2 llego a la rev 5, del mismo cliente me va a traer el pedido 1 con la rev 10,  yo necesito la máxima rev alcanzada que tuvieron cada uno de los pedidos de cada uno de los clientes es decir, el pedido 1 con su rev10 y el pedido 2 con su rev 5 de ese cliente y repetir esto con todos los clientes, es decir. si tengo 3 clientes que tienen 10 pedidos, yo necesito todos los pedidos de los 3 clientes con su ultimo nmro de rev

Comment: entonces no entiendo tus condiciones para agrupar.. no buscas maximos, buscas formas de agrupar, pero no agrupas por pedido. Agrupas por algo mas, y no queres un maximo de lo otro... disculpa, no termino de entender el problema

Comment: pedidos (todos), revisiones(la ultima de cada pedido) clientes(todos), ¿Ahora?

Comment: ah entonces agrupas por pedido, cliente y max(revision).. asi?

Comment: Claro hasta ahi llegue, pero me trae los pedidos con la revision mas alta y no todos con cada una de sus revisiones mas altas, se entiende?

Comment: cada cliente tiene su numeración de pedidos que a su vez tiene su numeracion de revisiones, si un pedido se edita se agrega una revisión dejando sin efecto la revision anterior, entonces es un dato que no me interesa recuperar. si yo hago esto `SELECT pedido, max(revision), cliente FROM listas_de_despacho GROUP BY pedido` me trae solo las revisiones mas altas de cada pedido, pero los pedidos pueden repetirse entre distintos clientes y deja afuera pedidos de clientes que tienen una revision menor

Comment: re importante, a tu group by le falta el campo cliente. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324), ese es tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, necesitas la lista sólo con las últimas revisiones. Me parece que lo puedes obtener de esta manera:

```
SELECT ld.listas_id AS listas_id,
    ld.lista_numero AS lista_numero,
    ld.revision AS revision,
    ld.fecha AS fecha,
    ld.proyectista AS proyectista,
    desglo_ld.codigo_qr AS codigo_qr,
    desglo_ld.codigo AS codigo,
    desglo_ld.descripcion AS descripcion,
    desglo_ld.cantidad AS cantidad,
    desglo_ld.largo AS largo,
    desglo_ld.desarrollo AS desarrollo,
    desglo_ld.color AS color,
    desglo_ld.peso AS peso,
    desglo_ld.superficie AS superficie
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM listas_de_despacho a
    WHERE a.listas_id IN (
        SELECT MAX(b.listas_id)
        FROM listas_de_despacho b
        WHERE a.lista_numero = b.lista_numero
            AND a.obra_id = b.obra_id
    )
    ORDER BY lista_numero ASC, revision ASC
) ld
INNER JOIN desgloce_de_ld desglo_ld ON ld.listas_id = desglo_ld.listas_id
```