# Error ¿Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Hola quisiera saber por que al ejecutar este bloque de consulta mysql, me aparece este error de error con el group_by ya intente ejecutandolas por separado y no me ha funcionado agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Estoy trabajando con tablas temporales para al final llamar las tablas temporales

campos de la tabla lecturas_dir_vto

```
lectura_id
valor - int (solo valores del 1 al 8)
fecha - datetime
```

Consulta principal

```
 SET @fecha_inicio = '2019-12-15 00:00:00';
SET @fecha_fin = '2019-12-16 23:59:59';
SET @nodo = 112 ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_direccion;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_lecturas;
```

Tablas temporal  temp_direccion

```
create temporary table temp_direccion (id double, nombre varchar(5));

insert into temp_direccion
(id, nombre)
values      (1, 'N'),
              (2, 'NE'),
              (3, 'E'),
              (4, 'SE'),
              (5, 'S'),
              (6, 'SO'),
              (7, 'O'),
              (8, 'NO');
```

Tabla temporal temp_lecturas;

```
create temporary table temp_lecturas as
select      lec.lectura_id,
              lec.valor,
              date_sub(lec.fecha, interval 5 hour) as fecha
from        lecturas_dir_vto as lec
where       lec.nodo_id = @nodo
  and lec.fecha between date_add(@fecha_inicio, interval 5 hour)
    and date_add(@fecha_fin, interval 5 hour);

set @total = found_rows();
```

Conulta final

```
select      round((100 * count(any_value(lec.valor))) / @total, 2)  as cuenta,
              any_value(dir.nombre) as nombre
from        temp_direccion dir
                left join   temp_lecturas lec on lec.valor = dir.id
group by    lec.valor
order by    dir.id;
```

Error:

```
 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sioma_app.dir.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: decime si esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324 no resuelve tu duda

Comment: Entonces la marcamos como duplicada @gbianchi

Comment: @Aprendiz no es exactamente la misma respuesta.. por eso le pregunte a OP

Comment: @gbianchi no es el mismo problema que me muestras pero gracias

Comment: @miguelandreszuñigaromero en realidad es el mismo problema.. si dir.id que es la columna por la que pedis ordenar, no es parte del group by, como va a saber por cual columan ordenar? o por cual de los dir.id que encuentre al hacer el group ordenar? es la misma teoria el problema... ;)

Comment: Hhh entiendo ahora si

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo estas haciendo un group by en una columna que no estas llamando en el select (y que no es parte de una agregacion)entonces te da error en el order by