# Optimizar consulta con ORM Eloquent Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Amigos tengo la siguiente consulta funcionando

```
SELECT us.name, us.id, COUNT(o.id) AS c_orders 
FROM users us, model_has_roles mhr, orders o 
WHERE us.id = mhr.model_id and mhr.role_id=2 
AND o.user_id = us.id 
GROUP BY o.user_id
```

el resultado es el siguiente:

```
name       id   c_orders
Luis        4     7
Alejandro   10    1
```

como podría optimizar esta consulta empleando el orm de laravel?
Les agradezco que me puedan ayudar todavía no tengo el dominio suficiente de eloquent.

He probando lo siguente:

```
 public function getOrders($status=null)
 {
     $sql = "SELECT us.name, us.id, COUNT(o.id) AS c_orders 
                        FROM users us, model_has_roles mhr, orders o
                        WHERE us.id = mhr.model_id and mhr.role_id=2
                        AND o.user_id = us.id                        
                        GROUP BY o.user_id";

                return ['ordenes' => $sql];
}
```

pero no logro mostrar el resultado que obtengo con mi consulta en su lugar obtengo esto:

> {
>   "ordenes": "SELECT us.name, us.id, COUNT(o.id) AS c_orders \n                        FROM users us, model_has_roles mhr, orders o\n                        WHERE us.id = mhr.model_id and mhr.role_id=2\n                        AND o.user_id = us.id \n                        GROUP BY o.user_id"
>   }

**ACTUALIZADO**

Con la siguiente consulta a nivel de sql nativo **estoy obteniendo los usuarios que tienen el rol de operario y que tienen ordenes de trabajos asignadas que luego los agrupo por la columna user_id de mi tabla orders.**
Entonces para conseguir ese resultado combino 3 tablas **users us, 
model_has_roles mhr y
orders o**

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
$orders = DB::table('users')
                        ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
                        ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')
                        ->select( 'users.id','users.name','orders.id as o_id', 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')
                        ->selectRaw('count(order.id) orders')
                        ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id')->get();
```

Tengo problemas con

```
 ->selectRaw('count(order.id) orders') 
 ->groupBy('orders.user_id')->get();
```

y me sale el siguiente error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order.id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `orders`.`id` as `o_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `rol`, count(order.id) orders from `users` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `model_has_roles` on `users`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`model_id` where `model_has_roles`.`role_id` = 2 group by `orders`.`user_id`) ◀"

**ACTUALIZADO 2PARTE**

Bueno realizando algunos cambios en mi consulta obtengo lo siguiente:

Consulta:

```
public function getOrders($status=null, $user=null, $month=null)
    {
       $orders = DB::table('users')
                        ->join('orders','orders.user_id','=','users.id')
                        ->join('model_has_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.model_id')
                        ->select( 'users.id','users.name','orders.id as o_id', 'model_has_roles.role_id as rol')
                        ->selectRaw('count(orders.id) orders')
                        ->where('model_has_roles.role_id', '2')
                        ->groupBy('orders.user_id', 'users.id', 'orders.id', 'model_has_roles.role_id', 'users.name')
                        ->get();

        return ['orders' => $orders];
}
```

```
{
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 5,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 7,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 8,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 9,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 11,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 12,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"o_id": 13,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
},
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Alejandro",
"o_id": 10,
"rol": 2,
"orders": 1
}
]
}
```

**Como obtengo la cantidad de ordenes de cada operario? es decir como obtengo que luis tiene 7 ordenes y alejandro tiene 1?**

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: @Shaz he probado lo siguiente pero por algun motivo no obtengo el resultado, si pruebo la misma consulta en phpmyAdmin obiamente obtengo lo que busco. Quiero implementar una manera "prolija" empleando eloquent

Comment: @Aprendiz como empleo eloquent?

Comment: @Aprendiz he actualizado mi pregunta. Lo que trato de decir es que así como esta la consulta en sql nativo obviamente en laravel no me esta funcionando. Por lo que entiendo hay una manera de pasar esa misma consulta a laravel cosa que escapa por el momento de mis conocimientos.

Comment: @Aprendiz corregi lo que  indicaste pero ahora recibo otro tipo de error es el siguiente: ```"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tecind.users.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `users`.`name`, `orders`.`id` as `o_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `rol`, count(orders.id) orders from `users` inner join `orders` on `orders`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` inner join `model_has_roles` on `users`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`model_id` where `model_has_roles`.`role_id` = 2 group by `orders`.`user_id`) ◀"```

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Era lo que te comentaba el día de ayer, estas agrupando de modo incorrecto, siempre en el `GROUP BY` deben ir las columnas que tomas en el `SELECT` excepto aquellas que sean calculadas por funciones de agregación, **lectura obligatoria** [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select), en tu gestor no sale ese error por que el modo estricto viene deshabilitado, pero Laravel lo trae activado por *default*

Comment: @Aprendiz no estoy seguro de como realizar el count con esta consulta, esa es mi duda

Comment: @Aprendiz por favor mira mi 2 actualizacion, como obtengo la cantidad de ordenes de cada opreario ?