# ¿Cómo puedo optimizar esta consulta para que sea más rápida con CASE y GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Tengo un problema con una consulta, me tarda demasiado en darme los resultados aproximadamente 10 a 15 minutos y si selecciono una fecha muy antigua me tarda de 40 a 60 minutos y aveces ni me muestra nada

Tengo la tabla **clientes** el cual de ahí uso el campo **IdCliente** y el campo **RazonSocial**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otra tabla **TiposContenedores** el cual de ahí uso el campo **idTipoContenedor** y el campo **TipoContenedor**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra tabla seria **viajes** en la cual se almacena él o los campos a sumar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí tengo la consulta espero y me puedan ayudar a depurarla

```
SELECT V.idCliente, C.RazonSocial, V.Pagado, 
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CantCont) FROM viajes WHERE idTipoContenedor=1 and idCliente=V.idCliente and FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' and FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59'),0) AS Seco20, 
    (SELECT Precio FROM Servicios WHERE idTipoContenedor=1 and idCliente=V.idCliente) AS PrecioSeco20, 
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CantCont) FROM viajes WHERE idTipoContenedor=4 and idCliente=V.idCliente and FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' and FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59'),0) AS Isotanque, 
    (SELECT Precio FROM Servicios WHERE idTipoContenedor=4 and idCliente=V.idCliente) AS PrecioIsotanque, 
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CantCont) FROM viajes WHERE idTipoContenedor=3 and idCliente=V.idCliente and FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' and FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59'),0) AS Seco40, 
    (SELECT Precio FROM Servicios WHERE idTipoContenedor=3 and idCliente=V.idCliente) AS PrecioSeco40, 
    IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CantCont) FROM viajes WHERE idTipoContenedor=2 and idCliente=V.idCliente and FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' and FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59'),0) AS Refrigerado, 
    (SELECT Precio FROM Servicios WHERE idTipoContenedor=2 and idCliente=V.idCliente) AS PrecioRefrigerado FROM viajes V 
INNER JOIN clientes C ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente WHERE V.FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' and V.FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59' 
    GROUP BY V.idCliente ORDER BY V.idCliente
```

Este es el resultado de la consulta

Muestra la **RazonSocial** de la talba **clientes**, el numero total de contenedores de la tabla **viajes**, el precio de la tabla **Servicios** que relaciona el **idTipoContenedor** de la talbla **TiposContenedores**, me da una suma total del total de contenedores junto con la suma del precio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo resultado con `EXPLAIN`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el resultado de **CASE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código sin modificar muestra todos los costos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código modificado no muestra la mayoría de los costos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aún sin conocer el explain plan, estructura de tablas o índices, puedo arriesgarme a decirte que tu "query" tiene un patrón muy poco performante: el uso de tantas subconsultas a nivel de columna. A veces no queda otra, pero en tu caso tienes forma de resolverlo de manera mucho más sencilla y seguramente con mejor rendimiento. Veamos por parte:

```
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(CantCont) 
               FROM viajes 
               WHERE idTipoContenedor=1 
                     and idCliente=V.idCliente 
                     and FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' 
                     and FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59')
           ,0) AS Seco20,
```

Lo anterior lo tienes repetido 4 veces para sumar, entiendo, por tipo de contenedor y es básicamente información que puede obtenerse desde la consulta principal, mediante una suma condicional:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor=1 THEN V.CantCont ELSE 0 END) AS Seco20,
```

La otra subconsulta:

```
(SELECT Precio FROM Servicios WHERE idTipoContenedor=1 and idCliente=V.idCliente) AS PrecioSeco20,
```

también es básicamente la misma, las 4 veces, solo cambia el contenedor, por lo que, ¿por qué no incorporar `Servicios` a la consulta principal y resolver todo de la misma forma anterior?:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN S.idTipoContenedor = 1 THEN S.Precio ELSE NULL END) AS PrecioSeco20,
```

En este caso, donde hacemos un agrupamiento, necesitamos una función de agregación, por lo que usamos `MAX`, entiendo, por tu código, que el precio por contenedor/cliente es el mismo, por lo que `MAX` nos asegura siempre el precio de cada contenedor.

Otros comentarios adicionales:

1. Si solo muestras las columnas para los contenedores 1,2,3,4 es una buena práctica filtrar solo estos en el `where`
2. Completa el `group by` con todas las columnas del `select`, no hacerlo es una [**aberración que te permite por ahora `mysql`**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359) pero se va de cualquier estándar.

Dicho todo esto, la idea es algo así:

```
SELECT  V.idCliente, 
    C.RazonSocial, 
    V.Pagado, 

    SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor = 1 THEN V.CantCont ELSE 0 END) AS Seco20,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor = 4 THEN V.CantCont ELSE 0 END) AS Isotanque,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor = 3 THEN V.CantCont ELSE 0 END) AS Seco40,
    SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor = 2 THEN V.CantCont ELSE 0 END) AS Refrigerado,

    MAX(CASE WHEN S.idTipoContenedor = 1 THEN S.Precio ELSE NULL END) AS PrecioSeco20,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.idTipoContenedor = 4 THEN S.Precio ELSE NULL END) AS PrecioIsotanque,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.idTipoContenedor = 3 THEN S.Precio ELSE NULL END) AS PrecioSeco40,
    MAX(CASE WHEN S.idTipoContenedor = 2 THEN S.Precio ELSE NULL END) AS PrecioRefrigerado

    FROM viajes V 
    INNER JOIN clientes C 
        ON V.idCliente=C.idCliente 

    LEFT JOIN Servicios S
        ON S.idCliente = V.idCliente
        AND S.idTipoContenedor = V.idTipoContenedor

    WHERE   V.FechaAlta>='".$fechaInicio." 00:00:00' 
        and V.FechaAlta<='".$fechaFin." 23:59:59' 
        and V.idTipoContenedor in (1,2,3,4)

    GROUP BY V.idCliente,
        C.RazonSocial, 
        V.Pagado

    ORDER BY V.idCliente
```

¿Puede que aún haciendo estos cambios, no percibas mejoras? si, puede ocurrir, ahí es dónde hay que batallar con el query plan, definición de índices, etc.

Comment: La aberracion en los group by esta explicada [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324)

Comment: Que tal Patricio, he intentado con la respuesta que me diste y lamentablemente me salio un error al correrla #1052 - La columna: 'idTipoContenedor' en field list es ambigua, y si cambio el select que ya tengo por el tuyo no me muestra ningun resultado

Comment: Es cierto, mala mía por copiar y pegar. Modifica `SUM(CASE WHEN idTipoContenedor ...` por `SUM(CASE WHEN V.idTipoContenedor  `, es decir `idTipoContenedor ` es una columna de `Viajes` y `Servicios` por lo que hay que usar siempre un alias.

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error, comento una foto para ver si estoy haciendo lo correcto, una pregunta... en el LEFT JOIN asi debe de quedar como me publicaste = V.idTipoContenedor

Comment: Debes modificar todo los casos, te faltan 3. De todas formas, actualicé mi respuesta, prueba directamente el nuevo código.

Comment: Que tal @PatricioMoracho primero que nada Feliz Año, probé tu código y todo excelente en cuanto a la rapidez de consulta pero algunos costos no me aparecen, modifique mi pregunta con capturas de pantalla

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `Precio` en la tabla `Servicios`?

Comment: Es decimal(5,0), a lo que no entiendo es por que unos si me salen y otros (la mayoria) no

Comment: Lamentablemente, no te puedo ayudar mucho más, hay que hacer "debug" de los datos, toma una sola fila que no te retorna datos en el precio, revisa las filas de `Servicios` para ese único caso de Cliente/Tipocontenedor, ¿hay datos? ¿hay más de una fila? ¿que precio tiene? Cualquier cosa, sino, date una vuelta por el [chat] y me haces un ping y la seguimos por ahí.

Comment: Muy bien Patricio muchas gracias por tu ayuda me fue muy útil