# ¿Cómo predominar un campo de fecha en el GROU BY de MYSQL, para evitar el NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, tablas

Mi problema es que quiero traer el listado de mesas(tables) con su respectiva reserva(bookings). El siguiente código sirve a medias, ya que lo que hace es que trae todas las mesas y sus reservas en un rango de tiempo. Pero -a la hora de agrupar por tipo y número de mesa- lo que hace es que agrupa sin tomar en cuenta la fecha que está en la tabla(bookings) y por lo tanto lo deja en nulo.

EJ:

(Esto me lo trae con el GROUP BY)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(Esto me lo trae SIN el GROUP BY)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consulta MYSQL:

```
 SELECT 
 t.id, 
 t.type, 
 t.number, 
 t.chairs, 
 t.status, 
 b.booking_id, 
 b.dateTime 
 FROM tables AS t  
 LEFT JOIN bookings_tables AS bt ON bt.table_id = t.id 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
   b1.id AS booking_id, 
   b1.date_time AS dateTime 
   FROM bookings AS b1 
   WHERE b1.date_time BETWEEN "2020-01-02 21:01:27" AND "2020-01-03 01:01:27"
 ) AS b ON bt.booking_id = b.booking_id 
 GROUP BY t.number, t.type 
 ORDER BY t.type, t.number;
```

**La pregunta es:**

¿Que debo de hacer para que la tupla que tenga la fecha predomine y no quede en null?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Intenta poner `MAX(b.dateTime) AS dateTime`

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta depende un poco del corte de la información que quieres ver, y no me queda del todo claro. Pero planteando que:

**1.- Propósito de cada entidad en el modelo de datos:**

- La tabla `tables` (preferiría que se llamara `mesas` ) representa las mesas del restaurant y sus características: ID, tipo, cantidad de asientos, etc.
- La tabla `bookings` representa las reservas y su única característica relevante fuera del ID es la fecha/hora solicitada.
- La tabla `bookings_tables` no representa una entidad tangible sino que es sólo una tabla de paso que permite una relación many to many entre tablas y reservas

¿Qué sentido tiene la tabla de paso, cuando bastaría que la tabla de reservas contuviera el ID de la mesa? Conceptualmente, **se justifica su existencia** dado que una misma reserva podría aludir a dos mesas (una cena con 30 invitados, por ejemplo).

**2.- Supuestos**

El ID y número de la mesa parecen representar lo mismo. Para este ejemplo vamos a decir que sólo tiene ID.

En ese listado una mesa no puede estar reservada y libre al mismo tiempo. La mesa está reservada si existe un registro en `booking_table` asociando la mesa con una reserva de esta noche. (O de la fecha que quieras revisar)

Aunque se podría, vamos a dejar fuera el caso en que una misma mesa tenga dos reservas para hoy, porque no puedes expulsar al comensal de las 21:00 que se quedó haciendo sobremesa para darle su mesa al comensal de las 23:00.

A consecuencia de lo anterior, cada mesa puede aparecer solamente una vez ya sea libre o reservada. Por lo tanto **no tiene sentido agrupar**.

Finalmente, una misma reserva podría aludir a dos o más mesas dado que el número de comensales justifique juntarlas.

**3.- Poblamiento**

Vamos a decir que  el restaurant tiene 4 mesas:

```
| id |  sillas | tipo
---------------------
| 1  |    4    | Mesa
| 2  |    4    | Mesa
| 3  |    6    | Mesón
| 4  |    6    | Mesón
```

Que has tenido 4 reservas. Una antes de ayer, otra ayer y dos para hoy.

```
| id     |  horafecha
-------------------------------
| 154554 |  2020-01-01 21:00:00
| 154555 |  2020-01-02 21:00:00
| 154556 |  2020-01-03 21:15:00
| 154557 |  2020-01-03 22:00:00
```

Y que la relación entre reservas y mesas es:

```
| id_mesa | id_booking
----------------------
|   1     | 154554
|   1     | 154555
|   1     | 154556
|   3     | 154557
|   4     | 154557
```

(la reserva 154557 es para 12 personas, así que ocupará las mesas 3 y 4).

---

#### Solución Propuesta

Bajo el supuesto que quieres ver una especie de "agenda de hoy para la cena del  restaurant", el producto final debiera entregarte información del tipo

```
| id_mesa | sillas | status    | id_booking | horafecha
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |  4     | Reservada |  154556    | 2020-01-03 21:15:00
|  2      |  4     | Libre     |     -      |  -
|  3      |  6     | Reservada |  154557    | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
|  4      |  6     | Reservada |  154557    | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
```

Con esto el administrador del restaurant se programa en base a que esta noche

- La mesa 1 está reservada a las 21:15
- La mesa 2 no está reservada
- Las mesas 3 y 4 están reservadas a las 22:30 por una persona que trae 12 invitados, así que hay que juntarlas. (misma reserva, 2 mesas)

---

Si estamos de acuerdo en todo lo anterior, yo señalaría que en la cláusula FROM donde pones:

```
FROM tables AS t  
LEFT JOIN bookings_tables AS bt ON bt.table_id = t.id
```

Hay un problema. Ese producto cruz contiene **todas las combinaciones de reservas  de toda la historia sobre todas las mesas**. La mesa 1 ha sido reservada 3 veces esta semana, pero no tiene sentido mostrarla tres veces en la consulta. Creo que por eso exploraste la idea de agrupar, que en este caso no aporta nada. Fíjate que:

```
SELECT 
  t.id as id_mesa,
  bt.id_booking as id_reserva
FROM mesas t
LEFT JOIN  bookings_tables bt ON bt.id_mesa=t.id;
```

Se trae las reservas de días anteriores:

```
| id_mesa | id_reserva
----------------------
|   1     | 154554
|   1     | 154555
|   1     | 154556
|   3     | 154557
|   4     | 154557
|   2     | NULL
```

Segundo, la subconsulta contra el segmento de fechas relevantes:

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
   b1.id AS booking_id, 
   b1.date_time AS dateTime 
   FROM bookings AS b1 
   WHERE b1.date_time BETWEEN "2020-01-02 21:01:27" AND "2020-01-03 01:01:27"
 ) AS b ON bt.booking_id = b.booking_id
```

Cumple con quitar las fechas ajenas a la cena de hoy, pero debido al LEFT JOIN, no constituye un filtro. (Sólo provoca que el campo de `fechahora` se liste como nulo)

Creo que la manera correcta sería que la subconsulta generase un listado con las reservas de hoy y sus respectivas mesas, sin usar un LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT id_mesa, id_booking, horafecha
  FROM bookings b 
  JOIN bookings_tables bt ON bt.id_booking=b.id 
  WHERE b.horafecha BETWEEN "2020-01-03 21:00:00" AND "2020-01-04 01:01:00"
  ORDER BY id_mesa;
```

Que tiene la forma

```
| id_mesa | id_booking | horafecha
-------------------------------------------
|   1     | 154556     | 2020-01-03 21:15:00
|   3     | 154557     | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
|   4     | 154557     | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
```

En la cual cada mesa aparece **solamente una vez** (porque dijimos que no se puede reservar la misma mesa dos veces el mismo día)

Contra esa subconsulta sí tiene sentido hacer el left join:

```
SELECT 
 t.id as id_mesa,
 t.sillas,
 IF(bookings_hoy.id_booking IS NULL,'Libre','Reservada') as status,
 bookings_hoy.id_booking,
 bookings_hoy.horafecha
FROM mesas t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_mesa, id_booking, horafecha
  FROM bookings b 
  JOIN bookings_tables bt ON bt.id_booking=b.id 
  WHERE b.horafecha BETWEEN "2020-01-03 21:00:00" AND "2020-01-04 01:01:00"
) bookings_hoy ON bookings_hoy.id_mesa = t.id ;
```

Como cada mesa aparece una vez en la tabla de mesas y en la subconsulta, esta vez el LEFT JOIN no genera filas duplicadas, y sólo tiene horafecha nula cuando la mesa está libre. Es lo que señalamos previamente como el formato deseado:

```
| id_mesa | sillas | status    | id_booking | horafecha
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1      |  4     | Reservada |  154556    | 2020-01-03 21:15:00
|  2      |  4     | Libre     |    NULL    | NULL
|  3      |  6     | Reservada |  154557    | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
|  4      |  6     | Reservada |  154557    | 2020-01-03 22:00:00
```

Te dejo un <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3160bd/2)</kbd> con el ejemplo.