# SUM me genera un resultado doble MYSQL...?

Tags: mysql, double

tengo la siguiente duda.

Estoy trabajando con dos bases de datos y las relaciono con un campo en comun que contiene el mismo valor.

**ON A.scrap = F.linea**

Estoy teniendo un problema al hacer una suma con esta relacion, me esta trayendo el valor correcto pero doble o multiplicado por dos.

Manejo fechas dos veces para que me traiga la informacion de dichas fechas correctamente, no se si mi consulta este de lo mejor organizada pero estoy obteniendo la informacion correcta, solo tengo problema con la suma hasta ahora.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT SUM(psb_produc)/SUM(psb_rate) AS TotalProd,
B.id,B.linea,B.DateTime,B.EndDate,A.id_employee,A.id_empatarollos,
MAX(E.description) AS HourF, 
SUM(F.total) AS TotalScrap
    FROM psb_smt.psb_produccion A
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_info B 
        ON A.id_psbinfo = B.id
    INNER JOIN psb_smt.psb_hours E  
        ON A.psb_hr = E.id_desc
    LEFT JOIN scrap.registro F  
        ON A.scrap = F.linea AND
        F.fecha>= '2020-02-07 06:40:00'  AND F.fecha<= '2020-02-07 16:10:00'
    WHERE A.DateTime>= '2020-02-07 06:40:00'  AND A.DateTime <= '2020-02-07 16:10:00' AND A.hour_psb = '1S_HOURS' AND A.statusdtp=0
    GROUP by B.linea
    order by TotalProd DESC
```

**Tabla produccion:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla registro:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En los registros que coincidan con **"Linea 05"** solo es uno y el valor es **"17.35"** si se multiplica este valor se obtiene **"34.70"** que es lo que arroja mi consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta no es clara y las imágenes se ven con dificultad. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y pon el dataset en texto para poder entender mejor. Te puedes ahorrar aquellas columnas que sean irrelevantes.

Comment: Esto tiene otro problema y esta respondido aca: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select.. eso puede ser uno de los problemas que tenes

Answer (score 0):

Te haría un comentario, pero necesito subir la reputación para poder hacerlo.

Mira, lo que yo veo es que vinculas dos veces la tabla A (info) con la tabla de employee (C y D). No sé por qué lo hiciste, pero relacionándolo con unos problemas que tuve yo, esas vueltas que haces con las relaciones devuelven cosas raras inesperadas. Yo que tú, trazaría una línea para definir bien el orden en que se vinculan las tablas, porque no da lo mismo.

Adjunto imagen que hice para aclararme mejor tus bd. Obvia las relaciones 1 a 1, lo dejé así solo porque no conozco como son las tuyas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ok, lo de la tabla info con employees estaba de mas no la necesitaba ya la quite de mi consulta, pero la suma se sigue haciendo, pero ahora la hace por "3" entonces esto significa que como van tres registros de esa hora lo multiplica por eso(Aclarando que son registros por hora)

Comment: Aahh, ya entendí. Hay un error grande de normalización. ¿El campo "psb_line" y el "scrap" de la tabla "producción" no guardan lo mismo? Por otro lado, no entiendo bien qué guardas en la tabla "produccion", pero al hacer el "ON A.scrap = F.linea" el motor de db no te entiende. Debes relacionar claves ÚNICAS. Y en ambas tablas ese campo tiene valores repetidos. El order by debiese ser F.linea y no B.linea. Hay errores tanto de normalización como de consulta, bro.

Comment: Edito: con claves únicas me refería a 1 a M o 1 a 1. Tu consulta estaría relacionando las tablas M a M así como lo tienes.