# Unir consultas en una sola

Tags: mysql

Tengo tres tablas. registros, cotizaciones y ordenes. Tengo consultas **separadas** agrupadas por mes.
Me gustaría tener una consulta agrupada por mes, pero en vez de tenerlas separadas, tenerlas **unificadas**, y donde no hayan movimientos que coloque un 0 o NUll, a partir de un rango de fecha. Actualmente las tengo por separado.
Nota: ingresos y egresos son movimientos de la tabla (registros)

Anexo los campos de fechas de las tres tablas:
Ingresos:

```
SELECT MONTH(r.fecregistro) as mes, SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos FROM registros AS r WHERE r.idestado <> 7 AND r.fecregistro BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15' GROUP BY MONTH(r.fecregistro) DESC
```

Egresos:

```
SELECT MONTH(r.fecregistro) as mes, SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos FROM registros AS r WHERE r.idestado <> 7 AND r.fecregistro BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15' GROUP BY MONTH(r.fecregistro) DESC
```

Ordenes:

```
SELECT MONTH(IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop)) AS fecorden
                         , SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden 
                      FROM ordenes 
                      WHERE id_estado <> 7 
                      GROUP BY MONTH(IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop)) DESC
```

Cotizaciones:

```
SELECT MONTH(c.feccotizacion) as mes, SUM(c.totalcotizacion) AS totalcotizacion FROM cotizaciones AS c WHERE c.id_estado <> 7 AND c.feccotizacion BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15' GROUP BY MONTH(c.feccotizacion) DESC
```

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera, pero los valores no son reales, además no sabría cual debe ser la tabla padre, teniendo en cuenta que es una consulta por rango de fechas. Es un informe de movimiento. Esta es la manera como intento hacerlo:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(c.feccotizacion) as mes, 
    ies.ingresos, ies.egresos, 
    SUM(c.totalcotizacion) AS totalcotizacion, 
    ord.totalorden 
FROM cotizaciones AS c 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT r.fecregistro, SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos, SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 2 AND r.idcategoria <> 8,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS egresos FROM registros AS r WHERE r.idmovimiento IN (1, 2) AND r.idestado <> 7 GROUP BY month(r.fecregistro)) ies 
    ON ies.fecregistro = c.feccotizacion 
    LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT IF(feciop IS NULL, fecicom, feciop) AS fecorden, SUM(totalorden) AS totalorden FROM ordenes WHERE id_estado <> 7 GROUP BY fecorden ) ord 
    ON ord.fecorden = c.feccotizacion 
WHERE c.id_estado <> 7 AND c.feccotizacion BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15' 
GROUP BY MONTH(c.feccotizacion) DESC
```

[![Quisiera que salga así][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUmzK.png[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mostras como tenes la informacion y como queres que salga?? solo necesitas un join por la columna por la cual agrupas, que es month...

Comment: @gbianchi amigo voy a subir una imagen de lo que sale en el último código, así quiero que salga pero no son los valores. Gracias.

Comment: @gbianchi listo ya subí la imagen de la ultima consulta que estoy intentando pero me muestra la mayoría en null cuando si existen registros.

Comment: primero y principal, te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/243344/324.. tu group by esta mal!

Comment: una vez que leas eso... para tener todos los meses o usas una tabla calendario con todos los meses, o usas la tabla que mas meses tenga.. y luego, no uses los sum dentro de los subqueryes, hace los joins simples, y las sumas y agrupamiento en la consulta principal...

Comment: @gbianchi cuando hablas de hacer los joins simples es hacerlo por el campo fecha de cada tabla? Si hago los joins simples, como incluyo las clausulas where de cada tabla para que me den los valores que espero? gracias.

Comment: los joins no tienen nada que ver con los where.. me refiero a que traigas las tablas sin agrupar ni nada.. solo los registros filtrados... y luego agrupes al final...

Comment: @gbianchi te refieres a algo como esto? SELECT MONTH(c.feccotizacion) as mes, SUM(c.totalcotizacion) AS totalcotizacion, SUM(IF(r.idmovimiento = 1,r.vlrregistro,NULL)) AS ingresos
FROM cotizaciones AS c 
            
LEFT JOIN registros AS r ON r.fecregistro = c.feccotizacion            
WHERE c.id_estado <> 7 
AND c.feccotizacion BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15'

AND r.idestado <> 7
AND r.fecregistro BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-15'
AND r.idmovimiento IN(1)
GROUP BY month(c.feccotizacion)

Comment: eso suena mucho mejor.. lo probaste?

Comment: @gbianchi Sí lo probé pero no funciona amigo. Me da unos valores que no corresponde.

Comment: mostra los valores de origen y que valores deberian ser... no tenemos forma de saber que los valores esten mal

Comment: @gbianchi sé que están mal porque cuando ejecuto la consulta de manera independiente si me muestra los valores reales.

Comment: Podrías colocar las tablas?

Comment: @Synay claro que sí. Ya subí un esquema.