# Mostrar pedidos agrupados, y separar los productos por comas - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo el carrito de compras. Como un pedido puede llevar más de una fila he creado un número consecutivo para poder asociar el pedido al mismo carrito. Pero mi problema viene a la hora de mostrar los productos que a comprado, creo que agruparlos los estoy agrupando bien, algún consejo?

**Mi controlador**

```
$pedidos = DB::table('orders')
                    ->select('idpedido', DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'), 'fecha')
                    ->where('id_cliente', '=', auth()->user()->id)
                    ->groupBy('idpedido', 'fecha')
                    ->get();
```

**Vista**

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($pedidos as $ped)      
     <tr class="dato_tabla">      
        <td class="center">{{ $ped->idpedido }}</td>
        <td class="center">{{ $ped->fecha }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ $ped->total }}</td>
     </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar los nombres de los productos separados por `,`.

Por ejemplo si el pedido trae más de una fila, pues que en la tabla se muestre los productos comprados separados por `,`. (ejp.) -> producto1, producto2.
En el caso de que el pedido lleve un único producto, no es necesario separar nada. Muestra 
 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una muestra del orden de los datos que obtienes al momento y como quisieras agruparlos (*puede ser un ejemplo en una imagen*) ayudaría a entender mas rápido la duda

Comment: Hola @BetaM que tal? mira si ahora se entiende mejor

Comment: En tu consulta ¿cuál columna es la que te recupera el nombre o nombre de los productos?

Comment: La columna se llama `producto` pero no lo traigo aun @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El agrupamiento que tienes al momento solo te serviría para valores iguales, como los nombre de los productos pueden variar entonces dicho agrupamiento no funcionaría.

Lo que puedes aplicar aqui para lograr agrupar múltiples elementos en una misma celda separados por algún símbolo es usar [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) con una sintaxis parecida a esta:

```
SELECT ......, GROUP_CONCAT(columna) FROM tu Tabla;
```

Ahora para su aplicación lo que puedes hacer es utilizar el método [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods):

```
->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(producto) AS Productos")
```

Comment: jejej falto esa mayuscula! que fallo más tonto, ya esta solucionado y se reproduce perfecto! gracias como siempre @BetaM . Si no es mucha molestia te dejo dos preguntas sin respuesta que me traen de cabeza. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/371213/pago-transferencia-bancaria-laravel - https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/370563/al-a%c3%b1adir-al-carrito-mantenerme-en-la-misma-vista

Comment: Hola @BetaM . Y se puede agrupar por una sola columna? pero poder traer más columnas?

Comment: El agrupamiento se debe hacer según el standar sql por las mismas columnas que tengas en el select, menos aquellas calculadas por alguna función de agrupación

Comment: Esque si quiero sacar mas columnas, el resultado al final no es el mismo

Comment: Aquí puedes leer mas al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359

Comment: Gracias! @BetaM