# Error al realizar sum dentro de un query

Tags: laravel, sql

me encuentro con problemas a la hora de realizar una consulta con un select y SUM , la consulta es la siguiente

```
$detalle_propuestas= DB::table('detalle_propuestas')
        ->join('propuestas','propuestas.pro_id','=','detalle_propuestas.pro_id')
        ->join('detalle_colecciones','detalle_colecciones.dc_id','=','detalle_propuestas.dc_id')
        ->join('cartas','cartas.card_id','=','detalle_colecciones.card_id')
        ->join('colecciones','colecciones.col_id','=','detalle_colecciones.col_id')
        ->join('users','users.usu_id','=','colecciones.usu_id')
        ->join('referencias','referencias.usu_id','=','users.usu_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(referencias.ref_val) as total'),'cartas.card_nom','cartas.card_img','propuestas.pro_id','propuestas.int_fecha','users.usu_nick','total')
        ->where('propuestas.pro_id','=',$id)
        ->paginate(5);
```

Mi intención por ahora es solo que sume la columna ref_val, pero obtengo este error

```
SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: la columna «cartas.card_nom» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación LINE 1: select SUM(referencias.ref_val) as total, "cartas"."card_nom... ^ (SQL: select SUM(referencias.ref_val) as total, "cartas"."card_nom", "cartas"."card_img", "propuestas"."pro_id", "propuestas"."int_fecha", "users"."usu_nick", "referencias"."ref_val" from "detalle_propuestas" inner join "propuestas" on "propuestas"."pro_id" = "detalle_propuestas"."pro_id" inner join "detalle_colecciones" on "detalle_colecciones"."dc_id" = "detalle_propuestas"."dc_id" inner join "cartas" on "cartas"."card_id" = "detalle_colecciones"."card_id" inner join "colecciones" on "colecciones"."col_id" = "detalle_colecciones"."col_id" inner join "users" on "users"."usu_id" = "colecciones"."usu_id" inner join "referencias" on "referencias"."usu_id" = "users"."usu_id" where "propuestas"."pro_id" = 8 limit 5 offset 0)
```

¿Cómo debo realizar correctamente este tipo de consultas?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: A parte de que el error se resuelve con la respuesta de esa publicación que te marco como duplicada, te aviso que deberías [leer esto](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results) pues al momento la paginación no trabaja bien con agrupamiento