# Contar Columnas y sumar valor de columnas

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy trayendo datos de varias tablas y ademas quiero poder traer la suma de una columna y el conteo de otra estoy usando esta consulta:

```
   $aceptadas= DB::table('detalle_propuestas')
        ->join('propuestas','propuestas.pro_id','=','detalle_propuestas.pro_id')
        ->join('detalle_colecciones','detalle_colecciones.dc_id','=','detalle_propuestas.dc_id')
        ->join('cartas','cartas.card_id','=','detalle_colecciones.card_id')
        ->join('colecciones','colecciones.col_id','=','detalle_colecciones.col_id')
        ->join('users','users.usu_id','=','colecciones.usu_id')
        ->select('cartas.card_nom','cartas.card_img','propuestas.pro_id','propuestas.int_fecha')
        ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
        ->where('propuestas.estp_id','=',1)
        ->selectRaw('count(propuestas.pro_id) as Total','SUM(propuestas.pro_precio)')
        ->get();´
```

pero recibo este error:

> TypeError
> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\MundoTCG\app\Http\Controllers\PropuestasController.php on line 50

Comment: No tengo experiencia en esto pero se me ocurre: y si en el selectRaw trajeras todas las columnas que necesitas? Así te evitas dos select en la consulta...

Answer (score 1):

El método `selectRaw()` te ayuda a procesar la obtención de múltiples columnas con una sintaxis de esta forma:

```
selectRaw("columna1, SUM(columna2) AS Total, columna1")
```

Es decir no necesitas aislarlas como las tienes al momento donde cada columna deseada esta en su propia pareja de comillas, entonces debería ser así:

```
selectRaw('count(propuestas.pro_id) as Total, SUM(propuestas.pro_precio) AS Total2')
```

Hecho lo anterior, debes considerar los siguientes puntos:

Por utilizar funciones de agregación en algunas de tus columnas en el `SELECT` entonces deberás [agrupar](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) por el resto de columnas que no pases por dichas funciones.

Dicho lo anterior entonces justo antes del método `get()` deberás agrupar de esta forma:

```
->groupBy('columna1', 'columna2', ......., 'columnaN')
```

Es decir en el `GROUP BY` solamente **no** incluirías a:

- propuestas.pro_id
- propuestas.pro_precio

Lo único que si debes considerar es que de acuerdo [con la documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods), este método puede recibir como segundo argumento un vector con los valores que pudiera usar para interpolar en consultas.

Te [recomiendo leas esta publicación al respecto de `GROUP BY`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359) hecha por @gbianchi

Comment: Modifique el select a solo ->selectRaw("cartas.card_nom,propuestas.pro_id,propuestas.int_fecha,count(propuestas.pro_id) as Total") ahora recibo este error: SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR: la columna «cartas.card_nom» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación LINE 1:

Comment: Añadiré detalles, pero ese error es por que no estás agrupando, pero igual checa la edición

Comment: tengo una duda si necesitara contar las propuesta.pro_id y ademas mostrar cada una , funcionara agregandolas en group y en el select?

Comment: ummm si quieres el conteo haces un count de esa columna en el select y (**si es que te entendí**) mostrar cada `propuesta.pro_id` entonces tal vez te tengas que servir de la función de MySQL llamada `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: necesito la propuesta.pro_id para ponerla en un enlace y entrar a ver los datos completo y tambien necesito saber cuantas propuestas hay

Comment: Por eso amigo, haces el conteo de esa columna y eso solo te devolverá un número, a parte en otra celda podrás obtener pero al menos a como lo entiendo con GROUP_CONCAT todas las filas de cada conteo

Comment: Disculpa estoy confundido pero cambie a ->selectRaw('count(propuestas.pro_id) as Total')
        ->groupBy('cartas.card_nom','cartas.card_img','propuestas.int_fecha') lance un var_dump y solo retorna el valor del count , si pongo el propuestas.id en el groupBy el valor de count pasa a hacer incorrecto