# Group By no funciona en mi angular app

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, angular8

llevo días buscando la solución a mi problema, he visto varios ejemplos en google pero ninguno me funciona.
Tengo una aplicación en angular 8, uso nodejs y como base de datos influxdb. Necesito obtener todos los datos de una tabla (measurement) agrupados por un campo(tag) específico. Cuando formulo la consulta en influxdb directamente me funciona

```
select * from "User" group by "id" order by DESC limit 1
```

Mi objetivo es obtener solo el ultimo valor registrado y no todos los datos que puedan existir con el mismo ID. Esta consulta lo hace a la perfección. No lo hago con el metodo **last** porque cuando la tabla tiene mas de un campo o valores nulos según he leido no funciona.

Sin embargo, cuando intento realizar la misma consulta pero en mi aplicación angular no funciona, si uso la variante **.query** me da error,

> Error: error parsing query: found  GROUP BY , expected ; at line 1,
> char 31

si uso la variante **.queryRaw** me devuelve solo un valor, pero sin ID ni nada, como si los uniera todos en uno solo. Este es mi código en angular.

```
router.get('/api/user', ensureAuth, function(req, res) {
   influx
      .queryRaw('select * from "user" group by "id"') // order by DESC limit 1
      .then(influxToJSON)
      .then((data) => res.status(200).jsonp(data))
      .catch((err) => {
         console.log('/api/userERROR: ', err);
         return res.status(500).jsonp({ message: 'Error en la base de 
      datos' });
    });

});
```

Comment: esa query esta mal.. no se porque tira el error, pero salvo las versiones viejas de mysql, en cualquier otra base de datos, ese query va a tirar error. mira esta respuesta a ver si te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select

Comment: @gbianchi lei la respuesta sugerida y entendí lo explicado, lo probe en la bd influx y perfecto, pero cuando lo pongo en angular solo me da un registro y yo tengo 50 en la bd, y arupados son como 20