# Seleccionar sumatoria de una tabla y el listado de empleados de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

Hola a todos por si en mi titular no queda claro, sí es algo confuso, lo que quiero es seleccionar la sumatoria total de cada "id_estilista" y los que no estén en la tabla "multas" están en el listado de "estilistas", la tabla multas tiene estos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De "multas" me interesa la suma total del campo multa, ya que hay id_estilistas que tienen varias multas.

Y la tabla "estilistas" (en la cual estan el resto de empleados que no tienen multas) tiene estos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta tabla me interesa unicamente el nombre y el sueldo.

He probado la solución de Mauricio y aunque se acerca a lo que necesito, debo hacer algo mas que salgan solo los 34, estilistas activos, he actualizado la pregunta con la ultima información que tengo, probando esta solución:

```
    SELECT estilistas.id_estilista
       ,estilistas.nombre
       ,consolidado.sum_multa, estilistas.estado
   FROM estilistas 
        left join (SELECT multas.id_estilista, SUM(multas.multa) sum_multa
                     FROM multas 
                    WHERE MONTH(multas.creation_date) = 3
                    GROUP BY multas.id_estilista) consolidado
        on estilistas.id_estilista=consolidado.id_estilista
    and estilistas.estado = 'A'
```

Y me da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven hay varios que tienen el estado 'E' de eliminado y quiero solo los que tienen 'A'

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: con un left join no pudiste?

Comment: Probe con esto: SELECT e.id_estilista, e.nombre, e.sueldo, SUM(m.multa), m.id_estilista FROM estilistas e LEFT JOIN multas m ON e.id_estilista = m.id_estilista group by m.id_estilista, pero no funciona

Comment: que quiere decir no funciona? y ese group by esta mal.. mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359

Comment: Okay lo hice de esta manera: SELECT e.id_estilista, e.nombre, e.sueldo, SUM(m.multa), m.id_estilista FROM estilistas e RIGHT JOIN multas m ON e.id_estilista = m.id_estilista WHERE e.estado = 'A' AND m.estado = 'A' GROUP BY m.id_estilista, funciona, pero me da 23, y los empleados activos son 34, y solo me muestra 23 de esta forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesita es:

```
 SELECT estilistas.id_estilista
       ,estilistas.nombre
       ,consolidado.sum_multa
   FROM estilistas 
        left join (SELECT multas.id_estilista, SUM(multas.multa) sum_multa
                     FROM multas 
                    WHERE MONTH(multas.creation_date) = 3
                    GROUP BY multas.id_estilista) consolidado
        on estilistas.id_estilista=consolidado.id_estilista
  WHERE estilistas.estado = 'A'
```

Comment: Y como incluyo estado = 'A' para estilistas? Me funciona tu solucion pero me falta incluirle estado = 'A' de la tabla de estilistas, cuando lo agrego al where, me da error

Comment: Editado para incluir el filtro por estado. No olvides calificar/votar la respuesta.

Comment: Probe tu solución pero sigue tomando los estilistas que estan eliminados :(, seleccione el estado para comprobar, y ciertamente selecciona aun, los estilistas que estan con estado = 'E' de eliminado, tu solucion me da 60 resultados y los activos son 34

Comment: He editado mi pregunta con el ultimo intento

Comment: Corregido, el filtro de estado debía estar en el WHERE. Ya lo probé con datos.

Comment: Gracias ahi si ya esta perfecto :)