# Número de resultado en select de mysql

Tags: mysql

Amigos como estan? los molesto para consultarles, estuve tratando de lograr que sobre este select aparezca el número de resultado por órden y no hubo éxito, alguna idea?

El formato sería:

orden 
1 - 
2 - 
3 - 
4 - 
5 -

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
SET @numero=0;
SELECT @numero:=@numero+1 AS orden, COUNT(stat.ipvisita) AS cantidad, COUNT(DISTINCT(stat.ipvisita)) as unicos, nota.titulo, nota.permalink, cate.nombrecat, nota.id as notanumero
                FROM estadisticas stat
                JOIN notas nota
            ON stat.idnota = nota.id
                JOIN categorias cate
            ON nota.categorianota = cate.idcat
            WHERE stat.desde = '2'
            AND DATE_FORMAT(stat.diayhoravisita, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
            AND stat.pais = 'AR'
            GROUP BY nota.titulo
            ORDER BY unicos DESC
            LIMIT 5
```

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: no bota ningun output?

Comment: Da cualquier número en lugar de ordenarlos desde el 1 al 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aca hay varios problemas

SQL tiene un orden de precedendecia para ejecutar una consulta. El orden en que lo hace, es importante para poder calcular que cosas hace.

Para empezar, tiene un group by que esta mal ([mira aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select))

Luego, el orden es super importante.. el where se ejecuta al momento de seleccionar una fila. Luego de eso se hacen las cuentas, luego se filtra, luego se ordena.. es importante entender que las cosas en sql pasan en un orden.

NOTA: si esto es para arreglar algo en la vista de tu programa y que muestre los numeros del 1 al 5, entonces NO. No deberias hacerlo asi. Tu consultas no deberian solucionar problemas que tengas al mostrar. Esos numeros, deberian ser agregados en la vista.

Ahora si, para solucionar esto, lo que vamos a hacer es desarmar tu query para que lo ultimo que hagamos, sea contar.

```
SET @numero=0;
SELECT @numero:=@numero+1 AS orden, t.*
FROM (select COUNT(stat.ipvisita) AS cantidad, COUNT(DISTINCT(stat.ipvisita)) as unicos, nota.titulo, nota.permalink, cate.nombrecat, nota.id as notanumero
            FROM estadisticas stat
            JOIN notas nota
        ON stat.idnota = nota.id
            JOIN categorias cate
        ON nota.categorianota = cate.idcat
        WHERE stat.desde = '2'
        AND DATE_FORMAT(stat.diayhoravisita, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
        AND stat.pais = 'AR'
        GROUP BY nota.titulo, nota.permalink, cate.nombrecat, nota.id 
        ORDER BY unicos DESC
        LIMIT 5) as t
```

Entonces hacemos todo lo que haga falta, y luego, usamos eso como entrada para el que sigue y agrega esos numeros.

Comment: Clarísima la explicación! mil gracias campeón!