# Columnas válidas e inválidas en group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

En una consulta sencilla MySQL acepta algunas columnas en `group by` y otras no.

Antes de seguir, he creado un espacio de pruebas [aquí](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dnLQrCuzZ7fXr7z33H9AqB/0).

Tablas:

```
* Carrera (ID, nombre)
* Alumno (ID, nombre, ID_CARRERA)
* Asignatura (ID, nombre)
* Notas (ID_ALUMNO, ID_ASIGNATURA, nota)
```

Sin agrupar:

```
    select a.nombre as Alumno,  c.nombre as Carrera
             from alumno a
             inner join notas n on a.id = n.id_alumno
             inner join carrera c on a.id_carrera = c.id
     group by a.id;

| Alumno  | Carrera      |
| ------- | ------------ |
| Claudia | Informática  |
| Juan    | Informática  |
| Pedro   | Arquitectura |
```

Y agrupando:

```
select a.nombre as Alumno,  c.nombre as Carrera, avg(n.nota) as Promedio
         from alumno a
         inner join notas n on a.id = n.id_alumno
         inner join carrera c on a.id_carrera = c.id
group by a.id -- SI
-- group by c.id  -- NO
-- group by Alumno -- NO
-- group by Carrera -- NO
-- group by a.nombre -- NO
-- group by n.id_alumno -SI

| Alumno  | Carrera      | Promedio |
| ------- | ------------ | -------- |
| Claudia | Informática  | 91.5000  |
| Juan    | Informática  | 79.0000  |
| Pedro   | Arquitectura | 87.0000  |
```

Y cuando no la admite dice, por ejemplo usando `c.id`:

> Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'test.a.nombre' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

No entiendo por qué si admite `alumno.id` y no `carrera.id`, así como los demás casos comentados en la consulta de agrupación.

¿Cual es la explicación?

Nota: El mismo caso en H2:

```
 group by a.id -- SI
-- group by c.id  -- NO
-- group by Alumno -- SI
-- group by Carrera -- NO
-- group by a.nombre -- SI
-- group by n.id_alumno --SI
```

Comment: El problema es al reves.. mira aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/324

Comment: Es una interesante pregunta, pero no sé si sea posible entender este comportamiento y ni siquiera si valga la pena. Tu consulta debiera tener esta agrupación `group by a.nombre,  c.nombre`, es como funciona el Ansi SQL y el 99% de los motores de BD adhieren en esto (menos mysql  <= 5.7). Lee el enlace que te han pasado que explican bien este tema.

Comment: Amigo los campos que no aparecen en el groupby y aparecen en el select deben aparecer con una función de agregación en el select

Comment: Muy bueno. La respuesta entonces es: Las clausulas group by en ANSI SQL deben si o si tener todos los campos que están en el select y que no se usan en una función de agrupación, definidos en el group by para saber como se tiene que agrupar.

Comment: Y tal como está planteada la consulta, para estar bien tiene que ser: group by carrera, alumno.