# me sale este error cuando intento buscar ventas de una fecha a otra

Tags: mysql, jquery

> Error on this Query:

> SELECT s.date,p.name,s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price,COUNT(s.product_id) AS total_records,SUM(s.qty) AS total_qty,SUM(p.sale_price * s.qty) AS total_saleing_price,SUM(p.buy_price * s.qty) AS total_buying_price FROM sales s LEFT JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.id WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-03' GROUP BY DATE(s.date),p.name ORDER BY DATE(s.date) DESC

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'almacen.s.date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

este es el codigo

> function find_sale_by_dates($start_date,$end_date){ global $db; $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date)); $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($end_date)); $sql = "SELECT s.date,p.name,s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price,"; $sql .= "COUNT(s.product_id) AS total_records,"; //$sql .= "SUM(s.qty) AS total_sales,"; $sql .= "SUM(s.qty) AS total_qty,"; $sql .= "SUM(p.sale_price * s.qty) AS total_saleing_price,"; $sql .= "SUM(p.buy_price * s.qty) AS total_buying_price "; $sql .= "FROM sales s "; $sql .= "LEFT JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.id"; $sql .= " WHERE s.date BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'"; $sql .= " GROUP BY DATE(s.date),p.name"; $sql .= " ORDER BY DATE(s.date) DESC"; return $db->query($sql); }

Comment: Buenas, tu consulta es demasiado ambigua, te invito a leer [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), además, edita la publicacion para darle formato de codigo al codigo, y explicar que sucede con tu problema.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Answer (score 0):

EN el modo estricto de SQL se necesita que todos los campos no agregados (los que no tienen SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc) esten presentes en el GROUP BY.

Por lo tanto, deberias agregar los campos que deseas mostrar en el group BY, ajustando `s.date` a `DATE(s.date)` para coresponder al GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DATE(s.date) as date,p.name,s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price,
COUNT(s.product_id) AS total_records,SUM(s.qty) AS total_qty,SUM(p.sale_price * s.qty) AS total_saleing_price,SUM(p.buy_price * s.qty) AS total_buying_price 
FROM sales s 
LEFT JOIN products p ON s.product_id = p.id 
WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2020-11-01' AND '2020-11-03' 
GROUP BY DATE(s.date),p.name,s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price 
ORDER BY DATE(s.date) DESC
```

En general los campos que colocas en el SELECT deben ser unicos para cada conjunto agrupado, de otro modo cualquier valor dentro del grupo se mostraria sin dar sentido a lo que se desea mostrar.

Esto quiere decir que los campos adicionales s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price deberian ser unicos para el grupo (por ello quiza sea mejor agrupar por el id del producto p.id en vez del nombre `p.name`)

Link a la documentacion y ejemplos:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

> SQL-92 y versiones anteriores no permiten consultas para las cuales la
> lista de selección, la condición HAVING o la lista ORDER BY se
> refieren a columnas no agregadas que no están nombradas en la cláusula
> GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas GROUP BY todos los campos de tu consulta SELECT debe ser agrupables también porque la consulta te mostrará un resumen de información, no un detalle. Es incorrecto intentar incluir o mezclar información detallada en una consulta que es de tipo Resumen como lo es cualquier consulta que utiliza GROUP BY. Por lo tanto, los campos en tu SELECT que no estén contenidos en funciones de suma o conteo, debes agregarlos en la GROUP BY, como tus campos

`s.date,p.name,s.destination,p.sale_price,p.buy_price`

Estos sugieren información detallada, pero si deseas incluirlas junto con funciones de agrupación como SUM o COUNT debes usarlas para agrupador por fecha, destino, precio de venta y precio de compra en tu GROUP BY.