# Consulta Mysql Count con Inner Join me trae todos los datos del ON, pero no cumple la condicion where. Trae repetidos

Tags: php, mysql, count

Tengo dos tablas las cuales están relacionadas por distintos campos, pero especialmente tengo que unir estas dos tablas por un campo especifico que se llama identificación.

El tema esta cuando cuando quiero hacer un `count()`, me trae todos los datos que coinciden con el ON, y no respeta ni cumple la clausula `where`.

aca explico lo que sucede, como sucede, en que entorno sucede y que espero que suceda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para simular el entorno

[Ingresar aqui para obtener estructura](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QMjvQfrtZPDfq1pW6jx2MoYDo6_2eO5wrsxmTNwqD3w/edit?usp=sharing)

Si entras al link, ejecutas la query y ejecutas esta consulta, simularas el entorno.

la consulta que me devuelve los datos es esta

```
SELECT e.identificacion,e.nombre_cliente, t.estado, COUNT(t.estado) AS 
'cantidadEstado'
  FROM transito t
INNER JOIN express e ON t.identificacion=e.identificacion
WHERE t.estado IN('A-CONFIRMAR','RECUPERADO','PACTADO', 'RECHAZADA',
'EN-USO','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','NO-EXISTE-NUMERO','NO-RESPONDE', 
'TIEMPO-ESPERA','SE-MUDO','YA-RETIRADO','ZONA-PELIGROSA','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO',
'N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO','NO-COINCIDE-SERIE') 
 AND t.id_recolector='1177' 
 AND t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-09%' GROUP BY t.estado;
```

la cual me devuelvee.

estado-------cantidadEstado

A-confirmar----2

recuperado----38

la cual me deberia solo traer

a-confirmar ----- 1

recuperado------- 4

si bien en la tabla express hay 16 registros que cumplen con al condicion porque es la misma identificacion, es unicamente para unir relacionar las dos tablas
con el ON.
pero despues le hago un where para que solo me contabilize los que cumplen la
condicion de el estado='' , el id_recolector='' y la fecha.
Y el resultado que trae es como que si ignorara el where y trae todo lo de ON.

Comment: ¿es obligación unir ambas tablas?, veo innecesario hacer el join para lo que necesitas... puedes hacer la consulta directamente a la tabla transito.

Comment: Estas consultando solo a la tabla Tránsito - `SELECT t.estado, COUNT(t.estado) as 'cantidadEstado' FROM transito t`

Comment: No entiendo @Excorpion

Comment: Si bien estoy consultado solo la tabla transito, en la tabla transito solo hay 5 registros que cumplen con la condicion.

Comment: Tal y como dice Diego, el INNER JOIN esta de sobra acá. La consulta solo trae datos de tránsito, no de express. Si quisieras traer datos de express, estarías haciendo una consulta a esa tabla, ejemplo `e.identificacion`

Comment: Es necesario, porque esta misma consulta es la primera de una serie que tengo que preparar, porque tengo que contar otros campos que solo hay en la tabla express y la relaciono con transito. Yo tambien hice lo mismo, solo consultando la tabla transito. Pero si o si tengo que hacerlo con inner join o sub consulta, porque la siguiente consulta que tengo que preparar es sobre otro campo de la tabla express y tambien esta relacionado con la tabla transito. Solo que para a modo de exponer la pregunta con claridad, reduci las tablas.

Comment: Ok, mira, además de los estados, cuales son las otras condiciones que debe cumplir el where? por que veo que el id_recolector debe ser 1117 y que debe estar entre 2 fechas, además de tener mas de 0

Comment: id_recolector debe ser 1177, las fechas deben estar en ese rango, tener mas de 0 me parece que no tiene que ser obligatorio. Pero esas tres condiciones tiene que cumplirse,  estado,id_recolector y fecha.

Comment: LA consulta esta respetando todo... lo que pasa, es que al no tener un group by, hace el count, y muestra cualquier cosa en los otros campos... mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Answer (score 0):

Al ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT t.estado, COUNT(t.estado) as 'cantidadEstado' 
FROM transito t
INNER JOIN express e ON t.identificacion=e.identificacion
WHERE 
t.estado IN('A-CONFIRMAR','RECUPERADO','PACTADO', 'RECHAZADA', 
'EN-USO','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','NO-EXISTE-NUMERO','NO-RESPONDE', 
'TIEMPO-ESPERA','SE-MUDO','YA-RETIRADO','ZONA-PELIGROSA',
'NO-TUVO-EQUIPO', 'N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO','NO-COINCIDE-SERIE') 
and t.id_recolector='1177' 
and t.fecha >= '2020-11-03' 
AND t.fecha <= '2020-11-09' 
GROUP BY t.estado HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente, por lo que creo que el problema debe estar en las condicionales. (Acá la única diferencia, está en la fecha '2020-11-09')

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### AHORA

La ejecucion de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT t.estado, COUNT(t.estado) as 'cantidadEstado' 
FROM transito t
GROUP BY t.estado
```

Da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu consulta esta bien. Lo unico que al ingresar una fecha donde no coincida con la condicion, vuelve a arrojar los mismos datos indeseados. Por ejemplo, solo hay fecha del 03-11-2020 al 09-11-2020, si ingresar una consulta del 03 al 10, vuelve a traer todos los resultados indeseados.

Comment: Acabo de agregar una edicion, mirala. El resultado que buscas lo consegui con la segunda consulta

Comment: Si, actualize la pregunta y tambien necesito traerme los nombres de la table express. Tu consulta esta buen y se acerca bastante

Comment: Entonces que te hace falta ahora ?

Comment: No me esta dando el resultado esperado bro. Al ingresar una fecha que no este registrada, vuelve a "descontrolarse el count()"

Comment: Entonces crea otro post, por que el problema es otro ahora.