# Sumar dos columas en ELOQUENT con Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente codigo con un join que consulta en dos tablas diferentes, necesito sumar los campos cantidad de la dos tablas.

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::select(DB::raw('sum('movimientos.cantidad') as Total','movimientos.codigo_material','diferencias.cantidad')) 
->join('diferencias','diferencias.codigo_material','=','movimientos.codigo_material') 
->groupBy('codigo_material') 
->get();
```

Comment: Creo que entonces sería prudente que edites la pregunta y gire en torno al *problema* que tenías con la consulta que expones en los comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los puntos que te puede dar problemas es que en la función de agregación pasas a la columna entre comillas, eso haría que se tome como una cadena de texto simplemente.

Anexo a lo anterior tienes un problema con el uso de comillas pues tanto para la sentencia como para el valor de `SUM` usas el mismo tipo, lo mas simple creo que sería la sentencia se envuelva en comillas dobles (**pero de nuevo el punto anterior importa y mucho**)

Aparte de eso puedes emplear 2 funciones de agregación `SUM` para obtener la sumatoria de 2 columnas, pues al momento nadamás los valores de una

Detalle menor pero yo usaría el método `selectRaw` para componer una consulta un tanto mas legible

Por otro lado el resto de columnas en tu `SELECT` que no se pasan en una función de agregación deberían estar en tu `GROUP BY`

Propongo entonces:

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::selectRaw('SUM(movimientos.cantidad) + SUM(otraTabla.otracolumna) AS Total,
                                        movimientos.codigo_material,
                                        diferencias.cantidad
                                    ')
                ->join('diferencias','diferencias.codigo_material','=','movimientos.codigo_material') 
                ->groupBy('movimientos.codigo_material', 'diferencias.cantidad') 
                ->get();
```

En relación al agrupamiento recomiendo [leas la respuesta de @gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)