# Al realizar Count con inner join se descontrola al consulta

Tags: mysql, spinner

Estoy queriendo contar las provinciass ,
consultando y relacionando dos tablas por numero de identificacion
al realizar la consulta normalmente, lo ejecuta bien.

```
SELECT t.identificacion, t.estado, e.provincia FROM transito t
 INNER JOIN express e
 ON e.identificacion= t.identificacion
  GROUP BY t.id;

esto me arroja
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual esta bien, pero al ingresar un count en la consulta

```
 SELECT t.identificacion, t.estado, e.provincia,
 COUNT(e.provincia) FROM transito t
 INNER JOIN express e
 ON e.identificacion= t.identificacion
 GROUP BY t.identificacion, t.estado;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resulado esperado seria

provincia

caba-macro ----3

caba-micro -----2

sacando identificacion y estado de la consulta claro.

Se descontrola el count. Les agradeceria si tienen alguna guia o sospecha de el porque se comporta asi.

Comment: Una de las primeras cosas que te recomiendo mirar es tu agrupamiento, [puedes leer esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Es lo mismo que te dijeron anteriormente Alvaro, creo que no leiste antes

Comment: No bro, si leei. He intentado de varias maneras, pero igualmente seguire investigando otros post referentes al tema group by.

Comment: Además en express e no tenias provincia, ahora aparecio

Comment: Si, esta es una tabla mas completa. Con la consultas similiares.

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que únicamente te interesa la provincia, saca el resto de campos de la consulta y obtendrás el número de registros por provincia:

```
 SELECT e.provincia, COUNT(*) 
   FROM transito t
   INNER JOIN express e
   ON e.identificacion= t.identificacion
   GROUP BY t.estado;
```

Para poder comprobar tus resultados, sería necesario que modificaras tu pregunta incluyendo el dataset completo (phpMyAdmin, Exportar)