# problema con consulta SQL en laravel y vue JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con laravel y vueJS

Tengo un problema con una consulta que llevo todo el día intentando solucionar y no hay manera. Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para registrar asistencias, poder crear actuaciones a estas asistencias, controlar usuario y los bonos que tienen estos.

Mi problema es que intento sacar las asistencias pendientes con esta consulta.

```
$asistencias = \DB::select(\DB::raw(" SELECT asistencia.codAsistencia, asistencia.fecha, bonos.codBono, asistencia.estado, contratan.activo, 
                                            contratan.codContrato, contratan.tiempoRestanteBono, asistencia.mensaje, users.nombre 
                                            FROM asistencia, users, bonos, contratan 
                                            WHERE asistencia.estado = 'pendiente' 
                                            AND contratan.bono = bonos.codBono 
                                            AND asistencia.usuario = users.id 
                                            AND contratan.activo = 0 or contratan.activo = 1 
                                            GROUP BY asistencia.codAsistencia
                                         "));

return $asistencias;
```

bien, con vueJS tengo un componente que me crea una tabla dinámica con las 3 asistencias pendientes que tengo.

luego, tengo en esa tabla un botón dinámico

```
<tr v-for="data in datosAsistencias" :key="data.codAsistencia">
                <td>{{ data.codAsistencia }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.fecha }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.mensaje }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.nombre }}</td>
                <td>
                    <select @change="cambiarEstado(data.codAsistencia, $event)">
                        <option value="0" selected>{{data.estado}}</option>
                        <option value="en_proceso">En proceso</option>
                        <option value="finalizada">Finalizada</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create" @click="visualizar(data.codAsistencia)">Visualizar</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Ese botón me llama a la función visualizar:

```
visualizar: function(codAsistencia){

            this.visualizarActuaciones(codAsistencia);

            let url = "/getDatosAsistencia/"+ codAsistencia;
            axios
                .get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    $("#datosAsistenciaModal").show();
                    $("#codAsistencia").val(codAsistencia);
                    $("#fechaAsistencia").val(response.data[0]["fecha"]);
                    $("#mensajeAsistencia").text(response.data[0]["mensaje"]);
                    $("#usuario").val(response.data[0]["nombre"]);
                    $("#estado").val(response.data[0]["estado"]);
                    $("#bono").val(response.data[0]["tipo"]);
                    $("#tiempoContratado").val(response.data[0]["tiempoRestanteBono"]);
                    $("#codBono").val(response.data[0]["codBono"]);
                    $("#codContrato").val(response.data[0]["codContrato"]);
                    
                    $("#tiempoRestanteBono").text(response.data[0]["tiempoRestanteBono"] + " Min");

                    console.log(response.data);

                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        },
```

Y aquí es donde tengo el problema... esta función llama a la fuinción del controlador getDatosAsistencia, y con esta consulta muestro los datos:

```
$asistencia = \DB::select(\DB::raw(" SELECT distinct asistencia.codAsistencia, asistencia.fecha, asistencia.mensaje, users.nombre, contratan.tiempoRestanteBono 
                                                    FROM asistencia, users, bonos, contratan
                                                    WHERE asistencia.codAsistencia = $codAsistencia
                                            AND asistencia.usuario = users.id
                                                    AND contratan.bono = bonos.codBono
                                                    "));

return $asistencia;
```

Pero el resultado son siempre resultados repetidos 3 veces... siempre y no se que estoy haciendo mal, si hago un var_dump($asistencia) obtengo un array de 3 elementos con la misma información. Pero lo más gracioso y que tampoco se porqué, es que para llenar una ventana modal con los datos de la asistencia, hay propiedades que no existe, dice, pero no es así... de algunas asistencias saca los datos y de otras no...

por ejemplo:

si doy click en una asistencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si ahora hago click en la que tiene el código 4:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fecha' of undefined
at app.js:2617
```

De verdad me encuentro desesperado ya, siento el post tan largo, pero tenía que explicarlo bien e intentar que se comprenda mi problema.

Ya he borrado cache. Tengo que decir, también que este problema lo tengo en el hosting, en local funciona perfectamente.

Gracias por la ayuda de antemano

**RELACIONES**

```
**table user**

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('nif');
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('direccion')->nullable();
        $table->string('perfil')->default('usuario');
        $table->integer('telefono')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**table bonos**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('bonos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codBono');
        $table->string('tipo',20);
        $table->integer('minutos')->unsigned();
        $table->Double('precio',5,2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**table asistencia**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('asistencia', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codAsistencia');
        $table->dateTime('fecha');
        $table->longText('mensaje');
        $table->bigInteger('usuario')->unsigned();
        $table->string("estado", 20)->default("pendiente");
        $table->timestamps();



        // hacemos la insercción aquí ya que la tabla debe estar creada
        \DB::table('bonos')->insert([
            ['tipo' => '1/2H', 'minutos' => '30', 'precio' => '20'],
            ['tipo' => '1H', 'minutos' => '60', 'precio' => '40'],
            ['tipo' => '5H', 'minutos' => '300', 'precio' => '175'],
            ['tipo' => '10H', 'minutos' => '600', 'precio' => '330'],
            ['tipo' => '24H', 'minutos' => '1200', 'precio' => '600'],
        ]);



        $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

**table actuacion**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('actuacion', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codActuacion');
        $table->dateTime('fecha');
        $table->Integer('tiempoEmpleado');
        $table->Integer('asistencia')->unsigned();


        $table->foreign('asistencia')->references('codAsistencia')->on('asistencia');

    });
}
```

**table contratan**

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('contratan', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('codContrato');
        $table->Integer('bono')->unsigned();
        $table->Integer('tiempoRestanteBono')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('activo')->default('0');
        $table->bigInteger('usuario')->unsigned();


        $table->foreign('usuario')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('bono')->references('codBono')->on('bonos');
    });
}
```

Comment: un par de cossa estan mal... el primer query que mostras esta definitivamente mal.. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select).. por eso puede que despues todo ande mal... y lo otro que esta mal es $("#codAsistencia").val(codAsistencia);... porque haces esas cosas en vue? yo arreglaria todo eso, a ver si esos no son tus problemas...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @gbianchi he usado jquery para facilitarme la vida, ya que tenía un for-each con vue para mostrar los datos de la asistencia y me duplicaba o triplicaba la información. Por otro lado, lo que he llegado a comprender del enlace que me has pasado es que debo de poner todos los datos de mi select en el group by¿?? lo extraño es que me pasa en el hosting, en local funciona bien

Comment: porque muy probablemente no te des cuenta, o de casualidad anda bien... pero el query esta mal y eso puede provocar otros errores segun como comento en esa respuesta. Tambien, tratar de arreglar un problema que viene de otro lado de esa forma esta mal... deberias usar vue como corresponde, y verificar porque te estan devolviendo datos de mas... vue no repite los datos, a menos que le digas que los repita... tal vez, deberias verificar todos esos problemas primero...

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu tiempo, pero no comprendo lo que quiere decir la respuesta que me has pasado...Lo he leido varias veces pero no lo llego a comprender. Por otro lado, ahora mismo lo de vue no me está influyendo en eso, ya que muestra los datos bien de todos los casos y en local también. Me dices que la consulta está mal, pero como podría arreglarla¿?? me encuentro muy perdido

Comment: tu select tiene 10 campos y tu group by 1... y no tenes ninguna funcion de agregacion.. todo lo que devuelve ese query esta mal, y no se como te influye eso en el resto de tu pregunta....

Comment: @gbianchi si hago algo así: SELECT distinct asistencia.codAsistencia, asistencia.fecha, asistencia.mensaje, users.nombre, contratan.tiempoRestanteBono 
                          FROM asistencia, users, bonos, contratan
                          WHERE asistencia.codAsistencia = 2
                                                AND asistencia.usuario = users.id
                          AND contratan.bono = bonos.codBono
                                                        GROUP BY
asistencia.codAsistencia, asistencia.fecha, asistencia.mensaje, users.nombre, contratan.tiempoRestanteBono

Comment: me siguen apareciendo datos duplicados

Comment: Yo creo que debes dividir esta pregunta en varios pasos. Ese query esta mal, las tablas estan haciendo un producto cartesiano entre si. Y de ahi, todo es para abajo. Deberias centrarte en hacer que ese query devuelva los datos que queres. De ahi en adelante, todo el resto te va a resultar mas simple.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias por tu tiempo en responder. Pero no me estás ayudando en nada, solo me dices donde está mi error, ya me he dado cuenta yo, pero no ayudas a una posible solución. Voy a cerrar la pregunta y hacer una nueva a acerca de la consulta.

Comment: era justamente lo que te estaba diciendo.. para poder ayudarte con tu consulta, necesitamos saber como se relacionan las tablas, un ejemplo de datos, lo que te sale, y lo que queres que te salga....

Comment: Voy a poner las migraciones de laravel para que así puedas ver las relaciones, por otro lado. quiero mostrar los datos que se ven en mi select. Son los datos de una asistencia en concreto. He aportado capturas de pantalla de la salida de mi query mal, pues quiero eso mismo pero para un resultado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116161/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-scorpions).

Comment: yo no se laravel.. se sql.. no puedo ayudarte con esa informacion...