# Duda en mysql nivel-basico

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando mostrar una categoria y cantidad de contenido que contienen,la consulta no me sale ordenado de mayor a menor, ni viceversa se muestran segun orden en que se crearon. El codigo:

```
SELECT c.nombre, COUNT(e.id) FROM entradas e
RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON e.categoria_id = c.id
GROUP BY e.categoria_id
```

si lo hago asi me tira de la siguiente manera:

```
genero |  count(e.id)

accion |  2

terror |  5

deportes |  3

plataformeros |  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que ordenar los resultados de tu consulta. Utiliza la clausula [ORDER BY](https://www.anerbarrena.com/mysql-order-by-5578/) para elegir bajo que criterio quieres ordenar tus resultados y utiliza DESC o ASC para elegir el orden.

En tu caso tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT c.nombre, COUNT(e.id) FROM entradas e
RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON e.categoria_id = c.id
GROUP BY e.categoria_id
ORDER BY COUNT(e.id)
```

Por defecto utiliza ASC (ascendente) significa que te dará los resultados del menor al mayor.

Comment: Gracias tambien por tu respuesta tambien soluciono mi problema

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta me parece debería quedar de esta forma:

```
SELECT c.nombre, 
       COUNT(e.id) AS Conteo
FROM entradas e
RIGHT JOIN categorias c ON e.categoria_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.nombre
ORDER BY Conteo DESC;
```

- Dale un alias a tu conteo y usa eso mismo para el ordenamiento
- A tu consulta le hace falta una [instrucción de *ordenamiento*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) sea con una intención ascedente o descedente, para este caso considero debería ser sobre la columna calculada
- En tu agrupamiento debes incluir todas las columnas de tu `SELECT` que no están o existen dentro de una función de agregación; para esto [sugiero leas esta publicación que lo explica a detalle](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select) y también la [doc. oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias en una respuesta me respondiste 2 dudas que tenia, (una no la formule).

Comment: lo estoy chequiando ahora gracias por tomarte el tiempo de pasarme documentacion.