# mas recientes de separados por coma de condicion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysqldb

Hola a Todos> Tengo la siguiente pregunta... Anteriormente Tenia esta consulta que me arrojaba los siguientes datos , el problema era que no me separaba por coma los registros para poder contarlos

```
SELECT
`N° Sector`,
`N° Serie`,
`Fecha de Chequeo`,
`Estado Gral.`,
Condicion,
count(*) as Total
FROM Extintores
group by Condicion,`N° Sector`
Order by `N° Sector`, Total Desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para poder separar por coma, y contar correctamente lo pude solucionar con esta siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
 extintores.Id,
`N° Sector`,
`N° Serie`,
`Fecha de Chequeo`,
`Estado Gral.`,
condicion.Condicion,
count(*) as Total
FROM Extintores
JOIN condicion
   ON find_in_set(lower(condicion.Condicion), lower(extintores.Condicion))>0
group by condicion.Condicion,`N° Sector`
Order by `N° Sector`, Total Desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el problema que tengo es que por ejemplo tengo el **Id 152** que contiene el número de serie **799163** y se separó por coma con **fecha 30/10** y el **Id 4 con mismo número de serie** con fecha del **25/08**, lo que necesito es que figure el ID más reciente con Número de Serie.
Es decir, el ID 4 ya no me debería figurar porque es fecha mas antigua.

Me deberían quedar solo los datos separados por coma del ID 152 con fecha del 30/10
Ya que son mas recientes que los del 25/04 del ID 4 con mismo numero de serie.

Comment: No entiendo realmente el problema. El titulo menciona la fecha mas reciente separado por coma. Y veo que has separado las condiciones.

Comment: ese group by esta mal y puede llevar a que lo que veas no sea real.. por favor mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/243344/324

Comment: el id 4 y el id 152 tienen el mismo numero de serie pero con fechas diferentes entonces de esos dos me deberían figurar solo los datos separados por coma del mas reciente que es en este caso el id 152

Comment: aun sigo sin poder resolver el problema