# Error en GROUP BY DESC, ASC

Tags: mysql

En *mysql workbench* y *xampp*, funciona normal, cuando lo subo a mi servidor **(digital ocean ubuntu 20.4)** me bota error en el `GROUP BY 'DESC'`:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC,mes DESC,

Probé usando `ORDER BY`, y quitando `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` de sql mode, también cambie en laravel el modo `'strict' => false` y nada, ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
SELECT anio,mes, SUM(IF(tipo=0,total,0)) AS compras,SUM(IF(tipo=1,total,0)) AS ventas FROM (
        SELECT 0 AS tipo, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%Y") AS anio,
        DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%m") AS mes_num,
                        CASE
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 1 THEN "Enero"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 2 THEN "Febrero"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 3 THEN "Marzo"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 4 THEN "Abril"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 5 THEN "Mayo"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 6 THEN "Junio"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 7 THEN "Julio"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 8 THEN "Agosto"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 9 THEN "Septiembre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 10 THEN "Octubre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 11 THEN "Noviembre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 12 THEN "Diciembre"
                    END AS mes, COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD,
                        SUM(`TOTAL`) AS total
                 FROM compras
                 GROUP BY anio DESC,mes DESC
                   UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 AS tipo, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_venta, "%Y") AS anio,
        DATE_FORMAT(fecha_venta, "%m") AS mes_num,
                        CASE
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 1 THEN "Enero"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 2 THEN "Febrero"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 3 THEN "Marzo"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 4 THEN "Abril"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 5 THEN "Mayo"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 6 THEN "Junio"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 7 THEN "Julio"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 8 THEN "Agosto"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 9 THEN "Septiembre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 10 THEN "Octubre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 11 THEN "Noviembre"
                    WHEN MONTH(fecha_venta) = 12 THEN "Diciembre"
                    END AS mes, COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD,
                        SUM(`TOTAL`) AS total
                 FROM ventas
                 GROUP BY anio DESC,mes DESC
        )AS tabla WHERE anio=2020 GROUP BY anio DESC, mes_num DESC
```

Comment: Estas agrupando, por que le estas diciendo que agrupe en desc ?? eso es order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo mal el `GROUP BY` 
`GROUP BY` es para agrupar, luego de agruparlos, debes ordenarlos con `ORDER BY`
Esto:

```
GROUP BY anio DESC,mes DESC
```

Cambialo a esto:

```
GROUP BY anio, mes
ORDER BY anio DESC, mes DESC
```

**Recuerda cambiar las 2 sentencias**

---

Además, debes agregar todos los campos del `select` al `group by`

> Las clausulas group by, en lo que se llama ANSI SQL (o sea sql standard, que es igual para todas las bases), deben si o si, tener todos los campos que están en el select y que no se usan en una función de agrupación, definidos en el group by para saber como se tiene que agrupar, en que orden. El orden de agrupación, lo da el group by, no el select.
> Fuente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/91033

Comment: le puse order by en los 3 campos requeridos y nada, ahora me sale otro error el del UNION ALL: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS tipo, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_venta, "%Y") AS anio, ' at line 21

Comment: Si haces cambios, y aparecer OTROS errores, primero siempre copia el error completo. Y si el error esta en otro lado, es por que tu problema ha cambiado, y el anterior se soluciono.

Comment: cuando en laravel estaba el modo: 'strict' => true, me pedia que este en el group by fecha_venta, pero eso me malogra todo el resutlado

Comment: @Fernandoabel el modo stricto siempre debe estar presente, por otro lado Laravel *solo te avisa* de los errores que MySQL tiene al procesar tu consulta.

Comment: Si tu error ha cambiado o los errores siguen apareciendo, primero, descompone tu consulta, y ve ejecutándola de a poco. No podemos usar los comentarios como chat, y tu problema inicial era order by. Asi que extendernos demasiado acá, no se puede.

Comment: Yo recomiendo que si esta respuesta te solucionó el problema inicial entonces la aceptes y abras una nueva con el nuevo error @Fernandoabel