# Asesoría sobre consulta en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una consulta un poco larga donde relaciono mas de 4 a 6 tablas en MySQL. Mi pregunta es para que me asesoren sobre ella, ya que la misma me genera un error:

```
Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'YappProd.c.nombre' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `c`.`clabe`, CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, 0)) as clave_rastreo, CONCAT(COALESCE(c.nombre,"")," ",COALESCE(c.apellidos,"")) as beneficiario, COALESCE(c.rfc,"XAXX010101000") as rfc, SUM(op_cobro_detalle.precio  +  (Select COALESCE(sum(op_ajuste.monto),0) from op_ajuste where op_ajuste.ajustable_type="Pedido" and op_ajuste.tipo in ("ajuste","bono") and op_ajuste.ajustable_id = op_pedido.idPedido) -↵                (Select COALESCE(sum(op_impuesto_chofer.iva + op_impuesto_chofer.isr),0) from op_impuesto_chofer where op_impuesto_chofer.idPedido = op_pedido.idPedido) ) as monto, CONCAT("Yapp Cash","") as concepto, CONCAT("YAPP1","") as empresa, CONCAT(COALESCE(nombre,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_paterno,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_materno,"")) AS nombre from `op_pedido` inner join `op_cobro_detalle` on `op_pedido`.`idPedido` = `op_cobro_detalle`.`detallable_id` inner join `sys_usuario_individual` as `c` on `op_pedido`.`idUsuarioChofer` = `c`.`idUsuario` inner join `sys_usuario` as `r` on `op_pedido`.`idUsuarioChofer` = `r`.`idUsuario` where `op_pedido`.`estatus` in (6, 7) and `op_pedido`.`tipoPedido` in (1, 2, 4) and `op_cobro_detalle`.`detallable_type` = Pedido and (`op_cobro_detalle`.`descripcion` Like %Envío% or `op_cobro_detalle`.`descripcion` Like %Propina%) and `r`.`idRol` in (14, 17, 21, 24) group by `c`.`idUsuario`, `c`.`clabe`, `beneficiario`, `c`.`rfc`) count_row_table)
```

Dicho error no quieren que suceda; creemos que esto se debe a las agrupaciones en diferentes campos, dejo la consulta a continuación para que me comenten y asesoren sobre ella:

```
$data = Order::select(
                'c.clabe',
                DB::raw('CONCAT(LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 999999.99), 6, 0)) as clave_rastreo'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT(COALESCE(c.nombre,"")," ",COALESCE(c.apellidos,"")) as beneficiario'),
                DB::raw('COALESCE(c.rfc,"XAXX010101000") as rfc'),
                DB::raw('SUM(op_cobro_detalle.precio  +  (Select COALESCE(sum(op_ajuste.monto),0) from op_ajuste where op_ajuste.ajustable_type="Pedido" and op_ajuste.tipo in ("ajuste","bono") and op_ajuste.ajustable_id = op_pedido.idPedido) -
                (Select COALESCE(sum(op_impuesto_chofer.iva + op_impuesto_chofer.isr),0) from op_impuesto_chofer where op_impuesto_chofer.idPedido = op_pedido.idPedido) ) as monto'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT("Yapp Cash","") as concepto'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT("YAPP1","") as empresa'),
                DB::raw('CONCAT(COALESCE(nombre,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_paterno,"")," ", COALESCE(apellido_materno,"")) AS nombre')
            )
            ->join('op_cobro_detalle','op_pedido.idPedido','=','op_cobro_detalle.detallable_id')
            ->join('sys_usuario_individual as c','op_pedido.idUsuarioChofer','=','c.idUsuario')
            ->join('sys_usuario as r','op_pedido.idUsuarioChofer','=','r.idUsuario')
            ->whereIn('op_pedido.estatus',self::$status)
            ->whereIn('op_pedido.tipoPedido',self::$typeOfOrder)
            ->where('op_cobro_detalle.detallable_type','Pedido')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('op_cobro_detalle.descripcion', 'Like', '%Envío%')
                      ->orWhere('op_cobro_detalle.descripcion', 'Like', '%Propina%');
            })
            ->whereIn('r.idRol',$idRol)
            ->groupBy('c.idUsuario', 'c.clabe', 'beneficiario', 'c.rfc');
```

Porque requiero una asesoría por lo siguiente que me piden:

- Usar Eloquent en dicha consulta.
- Se tiene que trabajar con la configuración actual de base de datos que se les proporciono el acceso
  y el proyecto debe de tener la configuración original que llevaba en la rama

A todo esto no quieren cambiar la configuración del archivo localizado en **config/database.php**

Pero tampoco quiere cambiar nada a nivel de la BD en el servidor por estas razones pido una asesoría técnica y poder hacerles entender el porque debe hacerse dicha configuración pedida

Comment: ¿Ese es el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: @BetaM Acabo de actualizar con el error completo que me da

Comment: El error que presentas me parece [se resuelve analizando con este conocimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select) por otro lado el método `whereIn` debe recibir 2 valores uno es el nombre de la columna y el otro es un array de valores `[]` parte de esos 2 detalles, **principalmente el primero**

Comment: Hermanito mil gracias vale no sabia que Mysql Obligaba a colocar los campos que se encuentren dentro del select en el GroupBy