# Consulta mysql para obtener el registro mas reciente de una persona

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito ayuda para preparar un query en mysql que me traiga el ultimo registro de cada usuario.
Tengo una tabla donde tengo almacenado registros de personas y se va actualizando cada cierta fecha.
Ahora lo que necesito es traer el ultimo registro de cada persona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba utilizando el siguiente query:

```
SELECT * FROM `sua` WHERE fechaInicio = (SELECT MAX(fechaInicio) FROM sua)
```

Pero solo me trae el ultimo registro.

Necesito que la consulta me traiga lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De hecho solo puedes hacer un `order by` para conseguir eso: `SELECT * FROM sua ORDER BY fechaInicio DESC` y con `LIMIT` ya consigues cuantos registros quieres

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a lo que proporcionas:

```
SELECT Id, trabajador, nombre, administra, MAX(fechaInicio) Fini, MAX(fechaFin) fFin
FROM sua 
GROUP BY Id, trabajador, nombre, administra
```

En la imagen que porporcionas no se observa el nombre completo de algunas columnas; así que deberás checar el nombre nombre y ponerla como corresponde.

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo a dar a la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si como parece, la fecha de inicio es única por `trabajador`, lo que puedes hacer es una subconsulta de agrupación, para obtener la máxima fecha de inicio por `trabajador` y luego emplearla en un `inner join` con la misma tabla, para filtrar las filas que correspondan:

```
SELECT S.* 
       FROM sua S
       INNER JOIN (
              SELECT trabajador,
                     MAX(fechaInicio) as fechaInicio
                     FROM sua
                     GROUP BY trabajador
           ) T
           ON T.trabajador = S.trabajador
           AND T.fechaInicio = S.fechaInicio
```

Comment: Hola, la primera respuesta es correcta?, la de roberto

Comment: @Japv, eso lo debería responder el autor, por mi parte creo que no es lo que se está preguntando.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que la fecha de inicio, no siempre es la misma para todos, la fecha puede variar según el empleado

Comment: Hola @PedroIslasReséndiz, no hay problema con eso, el tema es que un trabajador tenga repetida la fecha de ingreso.

Comment: No es fecha de ingreso, es fecha de modificación, es por eso que pueda tener la misma fecha, entonces lo que necesito traer es el ultimo registro....

Comment: Pero en ningún lugar mencionaste una fecha de modificación, a ver.. ¿Como se determina cual es el "último" registro por trabajador?

Comment: La fecha mas reciente es su ultimo registro de cada trabajador.

Comment: Pero ese es el tema, ¿cual es el último registro? en bases de datos no existe el concepto de último o primero, solo existe si hablamos de un determinado orden, en este caso, como ordenarías las filas para saber cual es el último registro? por FechaInicio? por FechaFin? por Id?

Comment: La fechaInicio mas reciente es el ultimo registro

Comment: Bien, entonces entiendo que mi respuesta resolvería tu pregunta, al menos como lo he entendido, has llegado a probarla? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Me servieron mucho sus respuestas.
Al final lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT id, 
       trabajadorID, 
       nombre, 
       divicionPersonal, 
       MAX(fechaInicio) FechaIni, 
       fechaFin 
       FROM `sua` 
       group by trabajadorID, nombre
```

Comment: Cuidado con esta consulta, es algo espantoso que permite hacer MySQL totalmente por afuera de estándar, no tienes garantía que las columnas correspondan a la última fila, la de la MAX(fechaInicio), lee esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/243359/31764. Saludos.

Comment: Entonces como aconsejarías resolver esto? alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Mi sugerencia es lo que te dije en mi respuesta, lo llegaste a probar?