# Valor "strict" de la configuración de Laravel para MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7

Tengo una query *Eloquent* con `groupBy` que falla con si no modifico el valor de *strict* de la configuración de MySql en el fichero 'config/database.php' de Laravel.

Como solución en mi caso, cambio:

```
'strict' => true,
```

por:

```
'strict' => false,
'modes' => [
    // 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
    'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
    'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
    'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
    'NO_ZERO_DATE',
    'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
    'STRICT_ALL_TABLES',
    'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
],
```

He consultado: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-is-changed y https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-solve-the-mysql-5730-sql-modeonly-full-group-by-problem entre otras páginas. Pero sólo me queda claro que no es recomendable ponerlo a *false*.

Por defecto *strict* esta en `true`. **¿Que implicaciones tiene exactamente poner *strict* a `false`?**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Igual me estoy adelantando, pero considero que tu problema de agrupamiento que *resolviste* poniendo a *false* el modo estricto se resuelve con la teoría y ejemplos que da @gbianchi en la respuesta que te enlazo

Comment: El strict mode siempre debería estar habilitado. Eso te ayuda a conocer qué problemas puedes, o no, tener al manejar la base de datos, como por ejemplo el Group By que acabas de comentar. Otro ejemplo podría ser, si tienes un campo VARCHAR(4) e insertas más caracteres (5), al final no obtendrás un aviso de ello, MySQL se encargará de eso por debajo, y no quieres eso, créeme. Tendrás data inservible y sin saber dónde está.