# Cálculo de porcentajes en una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, porcentaje

Tengo la siguiente duda. Estoy elaborando una consulta en MySQL para calcular los porcentajes de votos obtenidos en cada mesa por cada candidato (estamos simulando un proceso electoral). Sin embargo, con el código que les coloco, me arroja el cálculo de los porcentajes obtenidos por cada candidato con base a todos votos emitidos y necesito es que me de el % obtenido por cada candidato considerando cada mesa de votación.

Esta es la consulta que elaboré:

```
SELECT 
        estado.nombreestado as Estado,
        municipio.nombremunicipio as Municipio,
        parroquia.nombreparroquia as Parroquia,
        centrovotacion.centrovotacionnombre as CentroDeVotacion,
        mesacentro.numeromesacentro as Mesa,
        tarjeton.NombreCandidato AS Candidato,
        SUM(actovoto.Participo) AS CantidadDeVotos,
        ROUND(((SUM(actovoto.Participo) / (SELECT COUNT(actovoto.CedulaElector)
                    FROM
                        actovoto
                    WHERE
                        ((actovoto.Participo = 1)
                            AND (actovoto.idCandidato IN (1 , 2, 3))))) * 100),
                2) AS '%'
    FROM
    actovoto
        JOIN tarjeton ON ((tarjeton.idCandidato = actovoto.idCandidato))
        JOIN elector on (elector.cedulaelector = actovoto.cedulaelector)
        JOIN mesacentro on (mesacentro.idmesacentro = elector.idmesacentro)
        JOIN centrovotacion on (centrovotacion.idcentrovotacion = mesacentro.idcentrovotacion)
        JOIN parroquia on (parroquia.idparroquia = centrovotacion.idparroquia)
        JOIN municipio on (municipio.idmunicipio = parroquia.idmunicipio)
        JOIN estado on (estado.idestado = municipio.idestado)
    WHERE
        ((actovoto.Participo = 1)
            AND (tarjeton.idCandidato IN (1 , 2, 3)))
    GROUP BY 
    estado.nombreestado, municipio.nombremunicipio, parroquia.nombreparroquia,
    centrovotacion.centrovotacionnombre, mesacentro.numeromesacentro,
    tarjeton.NombreCandidato
    ORDER BY mesacentro.numeromesacentro, centrovotacion.centrovotacionnombre
```

Y lo que muestro en la imagen, es lo que me refleja la consulta en la columna de %:

[image: Texto]

A modo de reforzar la idea, lo que no sé es cómo hacer para que, por ejemplo, en el centro de votación "Concentración Bolivariana El Cascajo", en la única mesa que hay (mesa 1), los porcentajes de los candidatos Ocariz y Rodríguez, así como los votos nulos, se determinen con base a los 173 votos que hubo efectivamente en la mesa y así sucesivamente con el resto.

Bien sabría agradecer la orientación que me pudieran brindar.

Nota: Participó = 1 significa que la persona realmente ejerció el voto (lógicamente estará en 0 si no votó) y los ID de candidatos son 1, 2, 3, para Ocariz, Rodríguez y Votos Nulos, respectivamente.

Comment: mañana te podria ayudar mejor.. pero para empezar.. lee aca.. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select.. tu group by esta MAL

Comment: Listo @gbianchi, ya hice los ajustes en el group by, de acuerdo con lo que me indicaste. Muchas gracias. Sin embargo estaré atento de tu orientación o de cualquier otro compañero que pudiera atender mi duda, porque realmente me estoy iniciando con esto y no sé cómo manejar la inquietud que tengo. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: y ahora que arreglaste el group by, como dan los datos? sigue fallando en el mismo lugar?

Comment: Es correcto @gbianchi, todo continúa igual :(