# Por qué el GROUP BY no me agrupa correctamente? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

tengo un problema y es que al hacer un group by de una consulta con dos inner joins, me devuelve un resultado muy chapuzero, y que estoy siguiendo unos cursos dónde el tiene absolutamente el mismo código que yo y le devuelve los datos agrupados por **"marca de coche"** y **"nombre cliente**"

```
select c.marca, cl.nombre, sum(e.cantidad) from encargos e
inner join coches c ON c.id = e.coche_id
inner join clientes cl ON cl.id = e.cliente_id
group by e.cliente_id, e.coche_id
```

*el output que me da es este:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os fijáis, se repiten nombres y marcas, es como que al hacer group by de las dos columnas se lía, o quizá este haciendo yo mal la consulta.

**Gracias y feliz año.**

Comment: Es que si quieres que muestre cuantos coches de cada ha comprado... fíjate en los primeros dos resultados. Si los agrupa, qué nombre te devuelve en marca, Tesla o Seat??? Por otro lado, no le estás pidiendo que agrupe por marca tampoco, así que el resultado está correcto acorde a la consulta, pues no veo ningún caso que un mismo nombre aparezca dos veces *para una determinada marca*

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: @BetaM gracias! lo estoy leyendo

Comment: en la respuesta de Roger torné me lo resuelve, de todas formas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que cambiar es la parte del `group by`, pues quieres que te sume y lo agrupe por marca y nombre y no por cliente y coche, tal como lo tienes ahora.

```
select c.marca, cl.nombre, sum(e.cantidad) 
from encargos e
inner join coches c ON c.id = e.coche_id
inner join clientes cl ON cl.id = e.cliente_id
group by c.marca, cl.nombre
```

Comment: Gracias Roger, me ha funcionado y no me duplica nada ya, pero una duda, marca y nombre es lo mismo que cliente (nombre) y coche (marca), o quiza me estoy confundiendo yo? Gracias

Comment: ```select c.marca, c.modelo, cl.nombre, sum(e.cantidad) from encargos e
inner join coches c ON c.id = e.coche_id
inner join clientes cl ON cl.id = e.cliente_id
group by c.marca, c.modelo, cl.nombre```
Esta sería la forma mas correcta entonces, no? Añadiendo también el campo "modelo" del coche

Comment: Correcto, lo lógico es que tengas lo mismo en el `select` que en el `group by`, a excepción del `sum`