# Agrupar por ID del Vehiculo pero me ordene por la ultima fecha actual de la solicitud

Tags: mysql, group-by, orderby

Necesito de su ayuda, tengo que traer solo 1 registro de Vehiculo, pero necesito que me tome la ultima fecha de actualizacion de la solicitud ordenado descendente, pero no logro realizarlo, me lo agrupa por vehiculo, pero tomar la fecha al azar.

```
SELECT 
a.SO_ID, a.SO_VEHICULO, a.SO_ESTADO, a.SO_ALQUILER, a.SO_TRASLADO, 
a.SO_FECHA_ACT, b.VE_ID , b.VE_CLIENTE, b.VE_MARCA, b.VE_MODELO, 
b.VE_TIPO_MOTOR, b.VE_ANO, b.VE_KM, b.VE_PATENTE, b.VE_CHASIS, b.VE_FECHA, 
b.VE_TIPO_ABONO, d.MA_ID, d.MA_NOMBRE, e.MO_ID, e.MO_NOMBRE, f.TM_ID, 
f.TM_NOMBRE 
from SOLICITUD a, VEHICULOS b, MARCA d, MODELO e, TIPO_MOTORES f 
where 
b.VE_MARCA=d.MA_ID and b.VE_MODELO=e.MO_ID 
and b.VE_TIPO_MOTOR=f.TM_ID and a.SO_VEHICULO=b.VE_ID  
group by b.VE_ID 
order by a.SO_FECHA_ACT
```

Necesitaria que primero me lo ordene por SO_FECHA_ACT (campo DATETIME) y despues me lo agrupe

Intente con muchas formas: DISCTINT, haciendo subquery! Y no me funciona...
Alguna idea?

Comment: Tienes 2 problemas grandes: 1. Tu sintaxis de joins no es la adecuada [revisa esto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html), el segundo es que tu agrupamiento no es el correcto, [lee esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Siempre será más fácil ayudar con consultas SQL si se incluyen a) las definiciones de las tablas involucradas, b) algunos datos de prueba, y c) la salida esperada de la consulta con esos datos de prueba (y cuál es la que está entregando tu consulta actual). Cualquier consulta es correcta dependiendo del resultado deseado!

Comment: Si, Alfabravo, lo estoy haciendo, pero no encuentro resultados... Como son varias tablas se complica

Answer (score 0):

Les dejo la solucion para el que lo necesite

```
select * from (SELECT a.SO_ID, a.SO_VEHICULO, a.SO_ESTADO, a.SO_ALQUILER, 
                a.SO_TRASLADO, max(a.SO_FECHA_ACT) as 'SO_FECHA_ACT', b.VE_ID ,                   b.VE_CLIENTE, b.VE_MARCA, b.VE_MODELO, b.VE_TIPO_MOTOR, 
                b.VE_PATENTE, d.MA_ID, d.MA_NOMBRE, e.MO_ID, e.MO_NOMBRE, 
                f.TM_ID, f.TM_NOMBRE 
                from SOLICITUD a, 
                     VEHICULOS b, 
                     MARCA d, 
                     MODELO e, 
                     TIPO_MOTORES f 
 where b.VE_MARCA=d.MA_ID and b.VE_MODELO=e.MO_ID and b.VE_TIPO_MOTOR=f.TM_ID and a.SO_VEHICULO=b.VE_ID group by a.SO_VEHICULO) as a  
 order by a.SO_FECHA_ACT desc
```