# Excluir datos duplicados y solo mostrar informacion importante en una columna SQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada acceso_usuarios en la que tengo relacionado usuarios y sistemas disponibles

Aqui hago una consulta para obtener los datos importantes

```
$acc = "SELECT 
        usuarios.nombre, 
        usuarios.apellido, 
        usuarios.cedula, 
        usuarios.usuario, 
        usuarios.correo,
        sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema,
        acceso,
        edicion,
        eliminacion,
        agregar,
        acceso_total
        FROM acceso_usuarios
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON acceso_usuarios.id_u = usuarios.id_usuario 
        INNER JOIN sistemas_disponibles ON acceso_usuarios.id_sist = sistemas_disponibles.id_sistema
        ";
```

Esto me devuelve a traves del while:

[image: resultado de la consulta]

Como veran la informacion del usuario se repite, hay alguna forma para evitar que se me repita informacion del usuario y que en ves de eso junto en el campo `Sistemas registrados` la informacion que obtengo de ese campo, como por ejemplo: `Sistema Principal , Guardias`

Comment: Puedes agregarle un `GROUP BY laColumnaLLavePrimaria` donde `laColumnaLLavePrimaria`  sería una columna o conjunto de columnas que identifican de manera única cada fila. Para satisfacer las demandas del estándar SQL podrías agrupar aquellas columnas que no son únicas, como `nombre, apellido` etc. Aunque sin hacerlo funciona en MySQL no es una buena práctica dejarlas sueltas.

Comment: @A.Cedano intento agrupar lo que normalmente se va a repetir que seria usuario, sin embargo cuando lo agrupo solo me devuelve 1 fila ,pero ¿donde queda lo que nunca va a ser igual? que vendria siendo sistemas registrados, solo me muestra el primero

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario y la captura de pantalla no corresponde con la consulta. Si tú quieres más filas distintas con respecto a otras columnas, tienes dos opciones: 1. incluir esas columnas en el `GROUP BY`, por ejemplo, si quisiera agrupar por region y por país, eso se haría poniendo: `GROUP BY region, pais` ; 2. Otra forma sería poniéndolas agrupadas en el resultado y trabajando el resultado posteriormente, en ese caso, en el `SELECT` pondrías algo así: `SELECT  ... , GROUP_CONCAT(region, pais) AS lugar ...` Sea como sea, no me aclaro con tu último comentario.

Comment: A ver si me explico, tengo una tabla relacional, relaciono usuario y acceso al sistema, en esa tabla relacional yo le indico que puede hacer 0 = NO y 1 = SI , que pasa, son varios sistemas, entonces existe 1 usuario con 2 accesos distintos, uno para el sistema principal y otro para una guardia, la idea era mostrar 1 sola vez la informacion del usuario pero en el campo nombre_sistema deberia poder agrupar esa informacion para que me muestre "Sistema 1, sistema 2, sistema 3" etc..

Comment: Ademas la captura de pantalla corresponde a los resultados que quiero ver cuando realice el while

Comment: Si te refieres a esta columna: `sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema`  deberías obtener los valores agrupados poniendo esto: `SELECT .... GROUP_CONCAT(sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema) AS sistemas ...` Si no te funciona explica en la pregunta la estructura de las tablas y dinos qué resultados obtienes aplicando lo recomendado. El while no interesa aquí, el problema es con la consulta y eso es lo que estamos intentando resolver, entonces, muestra los resultados de la consulta. Luego, si tienes problemas con el `while` también se resolverán. Mezclar las cosas sólo confunde.

Comment: Oh perfecto, eso es lo que quiera mostrar, espero tu respuesta formal para colocarlo como correcto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar filas repetidas puedes usar [`GROUP BY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), por ejemplo:

```
GROUP BY (unaColumna, oVariasColumnas)
```

Poniendo entre paréntesis aquellas columnas por las que no quieres filas repetidas. Por ejemplo, si quieres una fila por usuario, pondrías el ID del usuario, que sería la columna que identifica de forma única a cada usuario. Y puedes agrupar por varias columnas de la misma o de varias tablas, según lo que necesites.

Las consultas con `GROUP BY` pueden combinarse también con [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) en el caso de que quieras agrupar en una sola columna varias filas posibles de una de las tablas.

Tu consulta podría entonces quedar así:

```
$acc = "SELECT 
        usuarios.nombre, 
        usuarios.apellido, 
        usuarios.cedula, 
        usuarios.usuario, 
        usuarios.correo,
        GROUP_CONCAT(sistemas_disponibles.nombre_sistema) AS sistemas,
        acceso,
        edicion,
        eliminacion,
        agregar,
        acceso_total
        FROM acceso_usuarios
        INNER JOIN usuarios ON acceso_usuarios.id_u = usuarios.id_usuario 
        INNER JOIN sistemas_disponibles ON acceso_usuarios.id_sist = sistemas_disponibles.id_sistema
        GROUP BY usuarios.LACOLUMNAIDDELUSUARIO
        ";
```

Debes cambiar `LACOLUMNAIDDELUSUARIO` por el nombre real de la misma.

### Advertencia

Esta consulta no es conforma al estándar SQL. MySQL es demasiado permisivo en las consultas de agrupación. Para hacer que la consulta sea estandarizada puedes agregar a la lista de `GROUP BY` todas aquellas columnas que no sean únicas, como `nombre, apellido`, o usar en ellas una función de agregación como  `MAX()` o `MIN()`.

Para más detalles sobre esto, puedes consultar la excelente respuesta de @gbianchi a la pregunta: [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/243344/29967)

Te recomiendo que escribas la consulta estandarizada.