# Error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 en laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

estoy trabajando con esta funcion que me retorna un json con datos de varias tablas: Los datos de un tecnico (nombre, telefono, etc) datos de un servicio asociado al tecnico (ftth, htc) y me deberia traer los datos de una o mas bodegas que tengan que como tipo_bodega tengan el atributo "Bodega Nuevos (lo especifico en esta linea ->where('bodegas.tipo_bodega','Bodega Nuevos')...

Esta es la funcion con la query que estoy usando:

```
public function getServicioTecnico($id){
        $tecnico = Tecnico::select('id','num_doc', 'nombre_primario','nombre_secundario','ape_pat','ape_mat','servicio_id','empresa_id')->findOrFail($id);
        $servicio = Servicio::select('servicio')->where('id', $tecnico->servicio_id)->first();
        $empresa = Empresa::select('razon_social')->where('id', $tecnico->empresa_id)->first();
        $data = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials')//ingreso_materials
        ->Join('ingreso_materials','ingreso_materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.ingreso_material_id')
 
         ->Join('materials','materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.material_id')
         ->Join('bodegas','bodegas.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.bodega_id')
         ->Join('servicios','servicios.id','=','ingreso_materials.servicio_id')
         ->Join('tecnicos','servicios.id','=','tecnicos.servicio_id')
         ->where('tecnicos.servicio_id',$tecnico->servicio_id)
         ->where('ingreso_materials.servicio_id',$tecnico->servicio_id)
         ->where('bodegas.tipo_bodega','Bodega Nuevos')
         //->groupBy(['bodegas.nombre_bodega'])
         ->distinct()
         ->pluck('bodegas.id');
          $bodegas = DB::table('bodegas')->whereIn('id',$data)->get();

         return response()->json([
            'data' => array(
                'tecnico' => $tecnico,
                'servicio' => $servicio,
                'empresa' => $empresa,
                'bodegas' => $bodegas
                )
        ], 200);
    }
```

El error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 se produce al parecer en esta linea:  ->groupBy(['bodegas.nombre_bodega']) ya que si quito esa linea, trae dato pero solo uno (deberia traerme al menos 3 segun lo que tengo en mi bd)

EDIT: He probado con esta linea:  ->groupBy(function($data) {return $data->tipo_bodega->}) , pero ahora arroja el error: stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Alguien ve algun error que me este pasando por alto? no consigo dar con el problema

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Hola @BetaM, segun entiendo entonces deberia en la linea del groupBy dejar solo 'bodegas'? no entendi mucho la verdad jej

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN: puede ser de ayuda a futuro para alguien, finalmente pude resolver el problema utilizando una subconsulta, quedando finalmente asi el metodo:

```
 public function getServicioTecnico($id){
        $tecnico = Tecnico::select('id','num_doc', 'nombre_primario','nombre_secundario','ape_pat','ape_mat','servicio_id','empresa_id')->findOrFail($id);
        $servicio = Servicio::select('servicio')->where('id', $tecnico->servicio_id)->first();
        $empresa = Empresa::select('razon_social')->where('id', $tecnico->empresa_id)->first();

        $data = DB::table('det_ingreso_materials')
        ->join('ingreso_materials','ingreso_materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.ingreso_material_id')
        ->join('materials','materials.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.material_id')->select('materials.id')
         ->join('bodegas','bodegas.id','=','det_ingreso_materials.bodega_id') ->select('bodegas.id')
         ->join('servicios','servicios.id','=','ingreso_materials.servicio_id') ->select('servicios.id')
         ->join('tecnicos','servicios.id','=','tecnicos.servicio_id')->select('tecnicos.id')
         ->where('tecnicos.servicio_id',$tecnico->servicio_id)
         ->where('ingreso_materials.servicio_id',$tecnico->servicio_id)
         ->where('bodegas.tipo_bodega','Bodega Nuevos')
         ->groupBy(['bodegas.id','servicios.id','materials.id','tecnicos.id','ingreso_materials.id','det_ingreso_materials.id'])
         //->groupBy(['bodegas.tipo_bodega'])
       /*  ->groupBy(function($data) {
            return $data;
            }) */
         ->distinct()
         ->pluck('bodegas.id');
         $bodegas=DB::table('bodegas')
        ->whereIn('tipo_bodega',function ($query) {
        $query->select('tipo_bodega')->from('bodegas')
        ->Where('tipo_bodega','=','Bodega Nuevos');
        })
        ->get();

         return response()->json([
            'data' => array(
               //$data
               'tecnico' => $tecnico,
               'servicio' => $servicio,
               'empresa' => $empresa,
               'bodegas' => $bodegas
                )
        ], 200);
    }
```