# Sumar columnas en PHP ¿Es posible?

Tags: php, mysql, android

Me gustaría saber si es posible sumar dos columnas en PHP, es decir, si yo en un listado tengo dos item con el mismo código, misma descripción, mismo precio pero diferente cantidad, el código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "select * from agregados where estado='1' order by codigo";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();
while($fila=$resultado->fetch_array()){
$insertado["codigo"]=$fila['codigo'];
$insertado["descripcion"]=$fila['descripcion'];
$insertado["precio"]=$fila['precio'];
$insertado["cantidad"]=$fila['cantidad'];
$insertado["estado"]=$fila['estado'];
array_push($listado, $insertado);
}

echo json_encode($listado);
$resultado->close();
?>
```

La idea sería que aparezca las dos filas ya sumadas y que en lugar de que aparezcan dos filas, solo aparezca una, adjunto captura de pantalla para que quede más claro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir en lugar de que aparezca que por un lado uno de los item tenga cantidad 8 y que el otro item tenga cantidad 2, ya aparezca una sola fila que tenga cantidad 10

Comment: Y si haces la suma y agrupamiento?

Comment: parece que con un group by de código, y un select que muestre sum() de las columnas afectadas podría servirte.

Comment: ¿Muestras el estado? ¿Cuál mostrar si esas dos filas tienen estados diferentes?

Answer (score 2):

Sencillamente haz la agrupación en la query:

```
SELECT
  codigo,
  descripcion,
  precio,
  SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad
FROM
  agregados
WHERE
  estado='1'
GROUP BY
  codigo,
  descripcion,
  precio
ORDER BY
  codigo
```

No he incluido la columna `estado` porque al estar condicionándolo en el `WHERE` no tiene sentido que la recuperes

Actualización

Añado precio en el group by

Comment: De acuerdo a lo mencionado en la pregunta _"mismo código, misma descripción, mismo precio pero diferente cantidad"_ no es necesario sumar precio, solo cantidad y el grupo podría ser solo por código.

Comment: @Triby que *... el grupo podría ser solo por código* no sería conforme al estándar. Cuando puede haber columnas repetidas en una consulta de agrupación el SGBD debería saber cuál de ellas elegir, sea poniendo esa columna en la lista del `GROUP BY`, sea poniéndola en el `SELECT` con una función de agregación como `MAX, MIN, SUM` etc. MySQL fue permisivo con eso en versiones anteriores, ignorando por defecto el `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` pero eso ya no es así en versiones modernas. Para más detalles puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/243344/29967) y la R. de @gbianchi.

Comment: @A.Cedano, insisto en lo que dijo OP _"mismo código, misma descripción, mismo precio pero diferente cantidad"_ y agrego lo que dijo gbianchi en su respuesta: _"En este caso nombrecategoria tiene en todas las filas lo mismo. Pero que paso, si con el tiempo la categoría cambio de nombre, ¿pero no de codigo?"_. ¿Por qué cambiaría la descripción para un registro y sería diferente en otros? De entrada, pensaría en que lo ideal es que código sea una FK y se debería extraer al menos la descripción desde otra tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en la respuesta de César se te indica el camino correcto en cuanto a la consulta, aún puedes simplificar el código PHP. Bastaría que pongas de forma explícita los nombres de columna y que uses un método `fetch` más acorde con lo que necesitas.

```
include 'conexion.php';

$consulta = "SELECT 
                 codigo, 
                 descripcion, 
                 MAX(precio) AS precio, 
                 SUM(cantidad) AS cantidad, 
                 estado 
             FROM agregados 
             WHERE estado='1' 
             GROUP BY codigo, descripcion
             ORDER BY codigo";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
$listado = array();
while($fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $listado[]=$fila;
}
$resultado->close();
echo json_encode($listado);
```

### Notas

1. Dado que no indicas claramente qué se debe hacer con `precio`, yo he optado aquí ad libitum por el precio mayor usando `MAX`. Si se debe hacer algo con el precio, como sumarlo, cambias a `SUM(precio) as precio`. También, he mantenido la agrupación por `descripcion`. Aunque MySQL lo permite (no en el modo estricto), las consultas de agrupación deberían escribirse siempre agrupando debidamente sea en el GROUP BY, sea con funciones de agregación, para que el SGBD sepa con toda claridad qué debe hacer cuando haya varias posibilidades, como de hecho ocurre aquí con las columnas mencionadas.
2. Como ves, dentro del `while` no se asignan valores a mano, ni se usa `array_push`. Eso no es necesario, porque al usar el método `fetch_assoc` nos trae los datos en forma de array asociativo, por lo que podemos ir metiendo cada fila con sus columnas directamente a `$listado` haciendo simplemente esto: `$listado[]=$fila;` Además, `fetch_array()` trae los datos dos veces, como array asociativo y numérico. Al poner las columnas de forma explícita en el `SELECT` tendrás exactamente los datos que necesitas y todo queda optimizado.

Comment: olvide aclarar que mi intención no es sumar precio, es poder sumar cantidad

Comment: @StephanieRM la consulta suma cantidad. En cuanto al precio, no queda claro qué quieres hacer con él. ¿Necesitas tenerlo en los resultados o no? Si lo necesitas puedes expresarlo como está, con `MAX(precio)` o ponerlo en la lista de `GROUP BY` en caso de querer agrupar por eventuales precios distintos.