# USO DE COUNT Y GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy buscando mejorar mi consulta! Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La intención es mostrar el NOMBRE_ASESOR que contenga clientes mayor a 30,000 y 3,000. Para esto tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
    SELECT
        NOMBRE_ASESOR AS NOMBRE_ASESOR,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAYOR_30K,
        SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 AND UTILIDAD_NETA  <= 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAYOR_3K
    FROM VSIGLO A
    WHERE UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 AND FECHA_OPERACION BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-30' AND NOMBRE_ASESOR = 'BRUNO HERNANDEZ MENDEZ'
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ASESOR
```

El resultado es el siguiente filtrando al NOMBRE_ASESOR = BRUNO HERNANDEZ MENDEZ fecha de operación del 01 - 30 de Octubre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo contar el número de clientes que su utilidad sea mayor a 30,000 y 3,000 ya que mi función cuenta el numero total de clientes que cumplen con esa condición, pero hay clientes con el mismo nombre y se requiere que su utilidad se sume para que cumpla esa condición. En realidad Bruno debe mostrar como resultado 12 clientes mayor a 3,000 y 1 Mayor a 30,000

En el resultado que muestro no se ven los 25 clientes porque esta agrupado por NOMBRE_CLIENTE

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me arroja la consulta es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso modifique la consulta con otros parámetros y se acerca, la consulta modificada es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
    NOMBRE_ASESOR AS NOMBRE_ASESOR,
    IF(UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000, COUNT(DISTINCT NOMBRE_CLIENTE),0) AS MAYOR_30K,
    IF(UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000, COUNT(DISTINCT NOMBRE_CLIENTE),0) AS MAYOR_3K
FROM VSIGLO A
WHERE UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 AND FECHA_OPERACION BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-30' AND NOMBRE_ASESOR = 'BRUNO HERNANDEZ MENDEZ'
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ASESOR
```

Y su resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: A tu consulta le hace falta un detalle importante en el agrupamiento: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select

Comment: Y cual es el resultado que te trae esa consulta?

Comment: O no estás publicando la consulta real, o no estás publicando los resultados reales, pero no hay manera que la consulta que publicas produzca los resultados que dices que produce.

Answer (score 2):

Aca hay 2 problemas... el primero es que tu group by esta mal.. para ver porque, mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Lo segundo, es que estas usando count, cuando debes usar sum (porque si no, contas 1 siempre).. y como si fuera poco, estan mal tus condiciones, porque algo que es mayor a 30000, siempre va a ser mayor a 3000, con lo cual estas contando cosas dos veces (a menos que sea a proposito)...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS MAYOR_30K,
SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 and UTILIDAD_NETA  <= 30000 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS MAYOR_3K
```

Comment: Gracias! Estoy leyendo que mi group by debe contener todos los elementos del select, pero referente a la condición si es a propósito saber cuantos tienen Mayor a 3,000 y cuantos 30,000. Lo que hago ahí es contar en la condición cuando se cumpla le coloque 1 y es así como enumero los clientes que lo cumplen.

Comment: Lo que se requiere saber es: El número de clientes que la suma de su utilidad neta sea mayor a 3,000 y mayor a 30,000. Sin que se repitan los clientes porque hay clientes que tienen operación diaria. En ese ejemplo Bruno debe tener Mayor a 30,000 = 1, Mayor a 3,000 = 12

Comment: Y entonces saca el campo que no queres...

Comment: Gracias, continúo probando pero sigo sin obtener el resultado. Hice la prueba con: COUNT(DISTINCT NOMBRE_CLIENTE) AS MAYOR_3K y un where donde utilidad_neta > 3,000 agrupando el nombre_asesor y me cuenta bien, como puedo meter una segunda columna para los 30K y doble condición! Grcias

Comment: No entiendo porque mi respuesta no es tu solucion. O ainplemente sacando el campo que no querias mostrar. No entiendo porque vas para otro lado. Tal vez si mostras en tu pregunta el resultado esperado podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Gracias, ya modifique mi pregunta!

Comment: Gracias! Han sido de utilidad las respuestas, pero hay una última situación que no logro mejorar. Se debe sumar la utilidad neta del grupo de empresas, ya que al sumar las empresas iguales el resultado llega a cumplir la condición, es decir se deben sumar las empresas iguales y después contarlas para generar la condición.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoAlcocerJuárez eso seria otra pregunta distinta? porque esta ya es un lio....

Comment: No, está dentro de la misma problemática. Arriba pregunto que mi función solo cuenta y hay empresas con el mismo nombre, el cual debo sumar la utilidad para poder contar. La ayuda me ha servido para perfeccionar el conteo pero continuó sin poder sumar la utilidad y en base al resultado de dicha suma contar. Gracias

Comment: Si, es tu misma problematica, pero es otro el problema... la query anterior a esta, tiene que devolver las sumas que vos queres. Y en ese caso, camba toda la respuesta. Cerra esta pregunta, y busca que hay mil preguntas sobre sumar campos... es mas, lo estas haciendo aca... lo que podes chequear es subconsultas, que es lo que vas a necesitar...

Answer (score 1):

creo que lo que necesitas es una consulta anidada. Es bonito tener un script mágico que resuelve todos los problemas, pero la mayoría de las veces la mejor solución es la más sencilla.

Yo haría lo siguiente: creas una consulta que te da la información base, que en este caso es la cantidad de clientes como lo describres, luego ese resultado se lo das a otra sentencia que genere la información como la debes presentar al usuario.

Algo parecido a esto:

```
-- esto agrupa la información como debo presentarla al usuario
SELECT 
    NOMBRE_ASESOR,
    SUM(MAYOR_30K) AS MAYOR_30K,
    SUM(MAYOR_3K) AS MAYOR_3K
FROM (

    -- esto nos da cuantos clientes tienen los criterios solicitados
    SELECT
            NOMBRE_ASESOR,
            SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAYOR_30K,
            SUM(CASE WHEN UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 AND UTILIDAD_NETA  <= 30000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAYOR_3K
    FROM VSIGLO A
    WHERE UTILIDAD_NETA > 3000 AND FECHA_OPERACION BETWEEN '2020-10-01' AND '2020-10-30' AND NOMBRE_ASESOR = 'BRUNO HERNANDEZ MENDEZ'
    GROUP BY NOMBRE_ASESOR

) Q
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ASESOR
```