# Como Sumar Total De Una Tabla Agrupada Por Mes

Tags: mysql, sum

tengo esta tabla generada de una consulta **mysql**, hasta aquí todo bien

La consulta es esta:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha) AS Fecha, SUM(monto) AS Total FROM paciente WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2020' GROUP BY MONTH(fecha);
```

```
| No. | MES        | TOTAL     |
| --- | ---------- | --------- |
| 01  | Enero      | 20,240.00 |
| 02  | Febrero    | 18,430.00 |
| 03  | Marzo      | 13,440.00 |
| 04  | Abril      | 15,350.00 |
| 05  | Mayo       | 14,085.00 |
| 06  | Junio      | 20,833.00 |
| 07  | Julio      | 30,750.00 |
| 08  | Agosto     | 27,410.00 |
| 09  | Septiembre | 11,020.00 |
| 10  | Octubre    | 30,700.00 |
| 11  | Noviembre  | 24,970.00 |
| 12  | Diciembre  | 23,880.00 |
```

Quiero ahora poner debajo la suma total de la columna total

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones muestras 3 columnas, pero en tu consulta solo pones dos columnas,  que columnas quieres mostrar?

Comment: Saludos y gracias por responder, no la puse ya que es numeros del 1 al 12, quiero el total, de la columna total, es decir sumar todo desde el mes uno al mes 12 y que me de el resultado, no se si se pueda hacer en esa misma consulta que tengo, no quisiera hacer 2 consultas

Comment: Entonces serían 3 columnas?

Comment: No, solo la columna que dice total, es como si agarrara en excel y sumara con el icono sum(a2:a13) ;)

Comment: Pero aquí no es asi  sql tiene sus reglas

Comment: Te estoy poniendo un ejemplo de lo que busco hermano :)

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es una union de lo que tienes con una consulta que te retorne el mismo numero de columnas en null, excepto la de la sumatoria total

Answer (score 2):

Con la opción `ROLLUP` de `GROUP BY` se agrega un renglón super-agregado:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(fecha) AS Fecha
     , SUM(monto) AS Total 
  FROM paciente 
  WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2020' 
  GROUP BY MONTH(fecha) WITH ROLLUP;
```

Si quieres cambiar la etiqueta para total, manipula el NULL de la tabla derivada:

```
SELECT if( Mes is null
         , 'Total'
         , monthname( concat_ws('-',2000,Mes,1) )
         ) Fecha
     , Total
  FROM ( SELECT month(fecha) Mes
              , sum(monto) Total
           FROM paciente 
           WHERE year(fecha) = 2020 
           GROUP BY Mes WITH ROLLUP
       ) t;
```

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, voy a probar

Answer (score 1):

Para eso deberías utilizar grouping sets o simplemente WITH ROLLUP, puedes buscarlos en la documentación de la versión de mysql que uses.

```
SELECT 
    MONTHNAME(fecha) AS Fecha
    , SUM(monto) AS Total 
FROM paciente 
WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2020' 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha) WITH ROLLUP;
```

Con el WITH ROLLUP se agregaría un registro de *TOTALES* por cada cambio de group, lo que yo lo aprendí como corte de control, con NULL en el campo mes y el super-total en el campo total.

Una cosa que siempre me pone incómodo es que mysql te permite colocar columnas que no estén en el GROUP BY y no estén dentro de una función agregadora, así que deberás hacer prueba y error para asgurarte que sea el resultado que esperas.

Saludos

Comment: Bien voy a probar

Comment: me saca lo que quiero, solo una cosa, como hago para que sea por ejemplo una variable y no me saque otro row con el mismo nombre del mes con el monto total, ejemplo ```<?php echo number_format($dados['Total'], 2) ?>``` eso tengo por ejemplo en mi while

Comment: Te viene todo en un solo resulset, en este caso en particular NULL en el mes indicaría que no es una "fila de meses" sino el super-total, con eso podrías ver de evitarlo/extraerlo en php. La otra seria en el select del mysql agregar una columna "agrupado" en el cual devuelvas el resultado de la función GROUPING que devuelve 1 si es un NULL de super-total y 0 si no, serit algo como select ... FECHA, ... TOTAL, GROUPING(MONTH(FECHA)) as agrupado ... (creo) y usar esa columna para diferenciarlo.

Comment: Para el problema del group by, es solo en versiones viejas, despues lo dieron vuelta. mira [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359)

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo lo siguiente:

```
select monthname(fecha) as mes, sum(monto) as total
from paciente
where year(fecha)='2020'
group by month(fecha)
union
select 'Total', sum(monto)
from paciente;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una consulta que usa el **operador de conjunto union**, para unir dos consultas. La primera consulta es la misma que ya tienes, que obtiene el monto por cada mes y la segunda, obtendría la suma total de todos los montos. Importante las dos consultas deben tener la misma cantidad de columnas del mismo tipo cada una.

Comment: Gracias @Japv tambien voy a probar tu repuesta, desde ya muy agradecido

Comment: @henry, dime te sirvio?

Comment: Este que me diste me tiro una suma mas de lo que era, los muchachos me recomendaron  WITH ROLLUP y GROUPING(), el rollup funciono a la perfección, solo que no doy con la consulta para agregar que yo pueda poner en esta consulta  el nombre Total y luego la suma 251,108 en la tabla, que sea una variable porque tengo un while asi `<?php echo number_format($dados['Total'], 2) ?>` para poder tu sabes modificar como yo quiera y darle formato :) te agradezco la atención ;)

Comment: @henry, por lo que entiendo ya eso es cosa de php, no tiene nada q ver con sql, quiza podrias hacer una nueva pregunta explicando bien esta nueva problematica