# Agrupar productos según la fecha mas actual

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero agrupar los productos según la fecha mas actual que se ingreso en laravel, pero tengo un problema al crear la función en el controlador.

```
public function all()
{
    $idUser = Auth::id();
  
    $product = DB::table('clients')
        
        ->join('codes', 'clients.id', '=', 'codes.client_id')
        ->join('products', 'codes.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->join('inventories', 'codes.id', '=', 'inventories.code_id')
        ->select('products.name', 'inventories.price', 'inventories.fecha_fact')
        ->where('clients.user_id', '=', $idUser)
        ->max('inventories.fecha_fact')
        ->groupBy('inventories.code_id')
        ->get();
        
    
    return $product;
}
```

Me arroja error, estoy usando la funcion max pero nose donde se coloca. Tengo la funcion en mysql y me funciona.

```
SELECT max(i.fecha_fact),
   p.name,
   i.price
FROM   clients cl
INNER JOIN codes cd
ON cl.id = cd.client_id
INNER JOIN products p
ON cd.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN inventories i
ON cd.id = i.code_id
WHERE cl.user_id = 1
GROUP BY i.code_id
```

Porfavor necesito su ayuda. gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes probar a poner el MAX ayudandote de DB::raw

```
->select('products.name', 'inventories.price', DB::raw('MAX(inventories.fecha_fact) AS fecha_fact')
```

Puedes ponser todo el select en DB::raw también

```
->select(DB::raw('products.name, inventories.price, MAX(inventories.fecha_fact) AS fecha_fact'))
```