# ¿Cómo excluir registros de una tabla resultado en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Soy nuevo en este mundo, sepan disculpar si la consulta no es del todo precisa o si mi código no es el mejor.

Tengo dos tablas: ventas y elementosfactura ambas tablas están relacionadas a través de un idVenta. Necesito con una consulta mostrar la cantidad pendiente por facturar de todas las ventas, es decir, la cantidad vendida menos la suma de las cantidades ya facturadas, excluyendo las ventas cuya cantidad pendiente sean cero (venta ya facturada en su totalidad)

La siguiente es la consulta que tengo, me da la información que necesito pero quiero excluir los resultados de la columna cantidadPendiente que sean cero

```
select ventas.Idventa, 
       ventas.Cantidad, 
       ventas.Cantidad - IF(sum(elementosfactura.cantidadFacturada) is null, 0, sum(elementosfactura.cantidadFacturada)) as cantidadPendiente
from ventas 
left join elementosfactura ON ventas.Idventa=elementosfactura.idVenta 
join clientes on ventas.Idcliente=clientes.idCliente 
where clientes.tipoCliente='Empresa' 
GROUP by ventas.Idventa
```

El resultado que obtengo que es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Los valores que quieres excluir provienen de una columna calculada que sería en este caso **cantidadPendiente**, entonces en este caso pudieras considerar como opción el uso de **`HAVING`** para que filtre aquellas filas que sean mayores a 0.

Ejemplo:

```
...............
...............
GROUP by ventas.Idventa, ventas.Cantidad
HAVING cantidadPendiente > 0
```

Por cierto tu agrupamiento no luce del todo correcto, aqui [te dejo un aporte en la misma comunidad que explica al respecto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select) recomiendo lo leas a detalle.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Usando el HAVING en efecto obtengo el resultado deseado. Ahora voy a leer mas sobre la entrada que me dejaste. Muchas gracias de nuevo.