# consulta sql no logro tener la lista de cours

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola tengo estas dos tablas

y me estan pidiendo hacer una lista de los titre cours  teniendo al menos dos formadores diferentes

por ahora he hecho esto pero no obtengo la lista

```
select * from cours as c inner join sessions as s where c.CID = s.CID;
```

me podrian dar una mano por fa se los agradeceria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, para saber los `CID` con dos o más `formateur`, podemos agrupar y contar los `formateur` distintos por `CID`

```
SELECT  c.CID
        FROM cours c 
        INNER JOIN sessions s 
            ON c.CID = s.CID
        GROUP BY c.CID
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.formateur) >= 2
```

Finalmente, puedes listar únicamente estos, usando lo anterior como subconsulta:

```
SELECT  *
        FROM cours
        WHERE CID IN (
                 SELECT     c.CID
                            FROM cours c 
                            INNER JOIN sessions s 
                                ON c.CID = s.CID
                            GROUP BY c.CID
                            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.formateur) >= 2
                )
```

Comment: @Marcos, En una sentencia estándar SQL con GROUP BY, solo podés poner en el SELECT las columnas por las que estás agrupando. MYSQL permite hacer cosas raras como agregar columnas y agrupar por una sola de ellas, que según creo recordar tampoco te garantiza un resultado consistente.

Comment: Disculpa, no quiero ser pesado, pero me interesa mucho. ¿Tendrás a mano algún articulo se hable de esto? Si tomo lo que comentas literal, entonces por ejemplo, ¿no debería agregar una columna `COUNT(*)` para saber cuantos son los registros? Entiendo que el resultado puede ser inconsistente cuando las columnas que se piden son las que varían (_ejemplo `formateur`_) pero no es el caso en las columnas de `cours`

Comment: No, es que el COUNT(*) termine siendo inconsistente, el tema es que no tienes garantía que las columnas que no están en el GROUP BY sean incluso de la misma fila, fijate esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359

Comment: Esta bien, es exactamente intente señalar hacia el final de mi comentario. En este caso puntual al agrupar por `CID`, el `titre` es idéntico en todos, por lo que no debería haber problema. Pero ahora me quedo claro el "porque". Gracias! =)

Comment: gracias @PatricioMoracho por tu ayuda