# Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'biller.invoices.id' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me funciona perfectamente en Laravel versión 8

```
$invoices = Invoice::selectRaw('*, sum(price) as partial')->groupBy('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

La estoy agregando a un proyecto de Laravel versión 6 y me genera el siguiente error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'biller.invoices.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *, sum(price) as partial from `invoices` group by `code` order by `id` desc limit 25 offset 0)
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: Lo estaba pensando, pero porque funciona en la versión 8 de Laravel así como está?

Comment: ¿El proyecto con Laravel 6 usa la misma base de datos?

Comment: Sí, todo lo que estaba en Laravel 8 lo emigré a la versión 6 porque tengo un módulo hecho allí y me pareció llevarlo para esa versión por temas de tiempo.