# Sumar datos de una columna dadas varias condiciones MYSQL

Tags: mysql, condiciones, group-by, sum

Tengo una base de datos en donde varias tablas estan relacionadas y quiero conseguir las horas trabajadas de cada empleado pero que sume (las horas trabajadas) si es que el servicio es el mismo (NameServices). Lo que deseo es que me devuelva las columnas 1 a la 4 pero en donde el nombre del servio sea el mismo sume la cantidad de horas trabajadas para asi obtener la cantidad de horas trabajadas por servicio en un rango de fechas dadas.

[image: Resultado de la consulta que hice]

Esta es la consulta que hice:

```
SELECT  Employees.NameEmployees, Areas.NameAreas, Services.NameServices, Roles.NameRoles, WorkedHours.Day,WorkedHours.IntervalStart,WorkedHours.IntervalEnd, timediff(WorkedHours.IntervalEnd,WorkedHours.IntervalStart) as workedhours
FROM EmployeesRoles 
inner join Employees ON EmployeesRoles.IdEmployees=Employees.IdEmployees
inner join Areas ON Employees.IdAreas=Areas.IdAreas
inner join Services ON EmployeesRoles.IdServices=Services.IdServices
inner join Roles ON EmployeesRoles.IdRoles=Roles.IdRoles
inner join WorkedHours ON EmployeesRoles.IdEmployeesRoles=WorkedHours.IdEmployeesRoles 
where (Employees.IdEmployees=(9) and  WorkedHours.Day between CAST('2021-07-01' AS DATE) and  CAST('2021-07-31' AS DATE))  order by NameEmployees
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema que tuviste con el group by?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con group by de esta manera

```
SELECT 
    Employees.NameEmployees, 
    Areas.NameAreas, 
    Services.NameServices, 
    Roles.NameRoles,
 SUM(TIMEDIFF(WorkedHours.IntervalEnd,WorkedHours.IntervalStart))/100/60 AS total_horas 
FROM EmployeesRoles 
INNER JOIN Employees ON EmployeesRoles.IdEmployees=Employees.IdEmployees
INNER JOIN Areas ON Employees.IdAreas=Areas.IdAreas
INNER JOIN Services ON EmployeesRoles.IdServices=Services.IdServices
INNER JOIN Roles ON EmployeesRoles.IdRoles=Roles.IdRoles
INNER JOIN WorkedHours ON EmployeesRoles.IdEmployeesRoles=WorkedHours.IdEmployeesRoles 
WHERE (Employees.IdEmployees=(9) and  WorkedHours.Day BETWEEN CAST('2021-07-01' AS DATE) and  CAST('2021-07-31' AS DATE)) GROUP BY Employees.NameEmployees, Areas.NameAreas ORDER BY NameEmployees
```

El group by te agrupará por el nombre de empleado y el nombre de la area , por cada uno de ellos hará una suma de la diferencia de tiempo de WorkedHours.IntervalEnd y WorkedHours.IntervalStart para obtener el tiempo total del empleado, finalmente lo divides entre 100 y 60 para asi transformar el tiempo en horas

Comment: Respecto de tu agrupamiento te recomiendo [leas esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)