# Crear array multidimensional con resultado consulta, agrupando por una de sus propiedades

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-8

voy a reformular la pregunta porque creo que no la he orientado como debía.

Actualmente tengo dos tablas en base de datos **TypeFactors**, **Factors** con relación `1:N`.

Para obtener los datos de dichas tablas realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
$factors = DB::table('type_factors')
        ->join('factors', 'type_factors.id', '=', 'factors.typefactor_id')
        ->select('type_factors.typename', 'factors.typefactor_id', 'factors.factorname')
        ->get();
```

Y obtengo un resultado del tipo:

[image: Resultado dd()]

Lo que me gustaría ahora es poder agrupar los datos obtenidos en un **arreglo multidimensional** antes de pasarlo a la vista; del **tipo**:

**Ejemplo:**

```php
[
  "Conocimiento y Aptitudes" => [
     // Aquí todos los resultados, con el mismo typename "Conocimiento y Aptitudes"
   ],
  "Responsabilidad" => [
     // Aquí todos los resultados, con el mismo typename "Responsabilidad"
  ],
  // ...
]
```

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola BetaM. Si le añado el ->get() para obtener los registros me lanza el siguiente error: {SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dbsigualdad.factors.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `type_factors`.`typename`, `factors`.`id`, `factors`.`factorname` from `type_factors` inner join `factors` on `type_factors`.`id` = `factors`.`typefactor_id` group by `type_factors`.`typename`)}

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Comment: No termino de entenderlo bien, en mi caso, en el momento que añado más campos del SELECT a la cláusula GROUP BY, la consulta ya funciona pero no me muestra los registros agrupados por TIPO DE FACTOR.

Comment: No tienes funciones de agregación.

Comment: Hola amigo @jmrufo, para poder ayudarte con esto, lo mejor es que hagas un `dd()` o un `var_dump` sobre la variable `$factors`... ejemplo `dd($factors)` y lo coloques en cambio de la imagen que tienes allí. También seria ideal que de un ejemplo claro de como quieres agrupar esos datos en el `Array`

Comment: Hola Josbert, acabo de cambiar el resultado de la consulta mysql por el resultado de hacer un dd().

Comment: @jmrufo, lo que quieres entonces es, agrupar en ese `Array` por grupos del mismo valor de `typename`. Ejemplo `['Responsabilidad' => [/*  esto sera un array con todos los que tengan typename igual a Responsabilidad */]]` ..?? ¿entendí bien?

Comment: Correcto. Mi idea es una vez agrupar los datos obtenidos por TYPENAME para luego pasarlos a la vista y poder recorrer el arreglo e imprimir los datos.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, dame unos minutos, analizare esto un poco y coloco una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, hace unas horas respondí una pregunta de otro colega de la *comunidad* que necesitaba, relativamente lo mismo, pero en **javascript** en vez de **PHP**. He adaptado aquella solución a **PHP** y es la siguente:

Con un `foreach` vamos recorriendo y comprobando, si existe el grupo actual, sino lo creamos y adicionamos el **item** así:

```php
// Obtenemos los resultados de la consulta
$factors = DB::table('type_factors')
  ->join('factors', 'type_factors.id', '=', 'factors.typefactor_id')
  ->select('type_factors.typename', 'factors.typefactor_id', 'factors.factorname')
  ->get();

// Creamos un Array de salida vacio
$output = [];

/** 
 * Recorremos el Array 
 */
foreach($factors as $item)
{
  // Si no existe el grupo según el tipo, lo creamos como Array vacio 
  if(! array_key_exists($item->typename, $output) )
  {
    $output[$item->typename] = [];
  }
  
  // Adicionamos el item actual al grupo
  array_push($output[$item->typename], $item);
}

// Acá debería pasar a tu vista el nuevo Array multidimensional $output
// ...
```

Esto debería funcionar muy bien para ti, agrupando según quieres por `typename`

---

No obstante, te daré un consejo, creo que deberías considerar y ver el uso de la **clausura** [groupBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping) de **Laravel** y de *SQL* en general.

También recuerda que tienes en tus manos, junto con **Laravel**, a [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) y sus relaciones.

Usar **Laravel** y no aprovechar sus funcionalidades es como moler el trigo teniendo harina en la despensa jaja. **Pero es solo un consejo**, tu usa claro, *lo que mejor te parezca y necesites*

Saludos :)