# Como puedo sacar el nombre y precio del producto mas caro por fabricante?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Devuelve un listado con el nombre del producto más caro que tiene cada fabricante. El resultado debe tener tres columnas: nombre del producto, precio y nombre del fabricante. El resultado tiene que estar ordenado alfabéticamente de menor a mayor por el nombre del fabricante.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS tienda;

CREATE DATABASE tienda CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE tienda;

CREATE TABLE fabricante (
codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,nombre VARCHAR(100) 
NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE producto (codigo INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,codigo_fabricante INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (codigo_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(codigo));

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Este es el codigo que e intentado utilizar pero no funciona y no aparece error alguno tampoco.

```
select   p.nombre ,precio,f.nombre from producto as p RIGHT JOIN fabricante as f on p.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo  group by f.codigo HAVING precio=(select max(precio) from producto);
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si indicas que error obtienes con esta consulta o en que parte necesitas de ayuda

Comment: el detalle esta en eso que no muestra ningun error cuando hago la consulta y tampoco muestra el resultado esperado

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta y a parte del enunciado y el código explica que comportamiento tiene tu query actual

Comment: Sería de mayor ayuda si pones el código y quien lo vaya a probar pudiese copiar y pegar, en vez de transcribir el código de la imagen.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Ahora, mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)... cuando entiendas eso, tu having no tiene ningun sentido ahi.. tu max deberia ir en el select, y tu consulta con eso ya deberia estar lista...

Comment: gracias por las recomendaciones, pero tampoco me funciono ya que si muestra los max , pero los nombres cuando se muestran no tienen relación con el precio max

Comment: Porque obviamente no miraste lo que te pase... y tu group by sigue estando mal....

Comment: En que gestor es MySQL o SQL Server? ya que agregaste ambos en las etiquetas

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta es mi solución para SQL SERVER, para esto te recomiendo hacer un join con OUTER APPLY

```
select f.nombre, p.*
FROM fabricante AS f
    OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT TOP 1 * 
                    FROM producto AS P
                        WHERE P.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo
                    ORDER BY precio DESC
    ) AS p
```

esto esta trae todo desde la tabla fabricante  por lo que si hay fabricantes sin productos traerá NULL en el resto de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PR.nombre as 'nombre del producto' ,T.Precio,T.[nombre del fabricante] 
FROM 
    producto PR
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX( P.precio) AS 'Precio',F.nombre AS 'nombre del fabricante',F.codigo AS codigo FROM fabricante F
    INNER JOIN 
    producto P
    ON P.codigo_fabricante=F.codigo
    GROUP BY F.nombre, F.codigo) AS T
ON T.precio=PR.precio and T.codigo=PR.codigo_fabricante
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento del código. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
  p2.nombre
  , p2.precio
  , f2.nombre 
FROM producto p2 
JOIN fabricante f2 ON f2.id=p2.id_fabricante 
WHERE p2.precio in (
    SELECT MAX(p.precio) 
    FROM producto p JOIN fabricante f ON f.id=p.id_fabricante GROUP BY f.id
);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica el funcionamiento de la consulta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.