# ¿Cómo hacer un COUNT de artículos que pueden aparecer en dos tablas diferentes con un GROUP BY por día hacia atrás?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta SQL para MySQL 5.7 que me dice cuantos personas se han conectado al menos una vez o han leido un email durante el año pasado para cada lenguaje (Lang) y me gustaria obtenerlo para cada dia desde que hay records en mi base de datos (hacerlo backwards).

Aqui esta mi schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)

;


CREATE TABLE unique_open_emails
    (`date` datetime, `lang` varchar(2), `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO unique_open_emails
    (`date`, `lang`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    ('2016-04-12 00:00:00', 'fr', 115434),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11357),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137481),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10296),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 125772),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 955480),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9269),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90716),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 26330),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87416),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88358),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 102515),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89867),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119146),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 133316),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90095),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16510),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 21530),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81581),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'es', 54321),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 29363),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90326),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 23961),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89000),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9484),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11845),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 41231),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 588),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16678),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 19674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130113),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 84719),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 123252),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4676),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17452),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136544),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15917),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 82787),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81620),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 135298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15643),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 80981),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 51827),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90554),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10277),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24432),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6651),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 64106),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119080),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 72659),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130004),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 22320),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136966),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11317),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 79031),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90800),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16149),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61463),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 5383),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10223),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88100),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91691),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 126),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86858),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1419),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89849),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15721),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86444),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130822),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 73991),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113969),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16779),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 71267),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61067),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89081),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24815),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91928),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 13071),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1942),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44012),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 52049),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6626),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7034),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 20442),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 75422),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16673),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17325),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7898),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 85226),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136557),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 134423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 68723),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'en', 118331),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136046),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136891),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9169),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88946),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 115919),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44492),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89783),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137482),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 38636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11227),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 108310),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4700),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17976),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 8580),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91316)
;
```

Intenté:

```
SELECT date(date),lang,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) n_personas
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unique_open_emails
    UNION
    SELECT session_time,
      Lang,user_id
      FROM sessions  
  ) c1
  WHERE date>NOW()-INTERVAL 1 year
  AND date BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) and '2016-04-13'
  GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'u.lang'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

y no sé hace por día hacia atrás.

Aqui esta el [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2f7d27422ff903d84d029f717c1d6777).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [GROUP BY de MySQL obliga a meter todos los campos del SELECT](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece entender que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT date(date) dia,lang,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) n_personas
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unique_open_emails
    UNION
    SELECT session_time,
      Lang,user_id
      FROM sessions  
  ) c1
  WHERE year(date)=YEAR(NOW()-INTERVAL 1 year)
  GROUP BY 1,2;

+------------+------+------------+
| dia        | lang | n_personas |
+------------+------+------------+
| 2020-06-29 | en   |          1 |
| 2020-06-29 | es   |          2 |
| 2020-06-29 | fr   |          3 |
+------------+------+------------+
```

Aunque, por la consulta que has intentado, buscas los accesos del último año y no los del año pasado:

```
SELECT date(date) dia,lang,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) n_personas
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unique_open_emails
    UNION
    SELECT session_time,
      Lang,user_id
      FROM sessions  
  ) c1
  WHERE date>NOW()-INTERVAL 1 year
  GROUP BY 1,2;

+------------+------+------------+
| dia        | lang | n_personas |
+------------+------+------------+
| 2021-06-29 | en   |          1 |
| 2021-06-29 | es   |          2 |
| 2021-06-29 | fr   |          3 |
| 2021-07-29 | en   |          1 |
| 2021-07-29 | es   |          2 |
| 2021-07-29 | fr   |          3 |
+------------+------+------------+
```

En respuesta a tu comentario, me parece entender que buscas los datos desde un año antes del último email abierto:

```
SELECT date(date) dia,lang,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) n_personas
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM unique_open_emails
    UNION
    SELECT session_time,
      Lang,user_id
      FROM sessions  
  ) c1
  WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM unique_open_emails
      WHERE DATE>(
        SELECT MAX(date)-INTERVAL 1 year
          FROM unique_open_emails  
      )
  )
  GROUP BY 1,2;

+------------+------+------------+
| dia        | lang | n_personas |
+------------+------+------------+
| 2016-04-12 | fr   |          1 |
| 2016-04-13 | en   |          1 |
| 2016-04-13 | es   |          1 |
| 2016-04-13 | fr   |        111 |
| 2020-06-29 | es   |          1 |
| 2020-06-29 | fr   |          1 |
| 2021-06-29 | fr   |          1 |
| 2021-07-29 | fr   |          1 |
+------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Sin embargo, me gustaría obtener el número de usuarios vivos (que han tenido actividad en el último año) para todos los días hasta el último día que un usuario estuvo activo. Por ejemplo aqui el ultimo dia es 2016-04-13. Así que yo buscaría este número de usuarios activos, al menos en el último año para todas las fechas desde ahora hasta el 2016-04-13 ( que, por lo tanto, se verá hasta un año antes :))

Comment: La verdad es que no logro entender muy bien a qué te refieres. Por favor, modifica tu pregunta añadiendo el resultado que esperas a ver si nos cuadran los resultados. En cualquier caso, modifico la pregunta incorporando lo que me ha parecido entender.