# agrupar group by sql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

para ser claro puse un ejemplo sencillo, lo que quiero es agrupar en mi sentencia nombrando una sola columna, es decir que no sea necesario nombrar en mi group by las dos columnas, se que si las nombro las dos estas me imprimira los datos, pero para el verdadero ejercicio me es necesario nombrar una asola columna, a continuacion el ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE ejemplo (id int identity, columna1 varchar(50),columna2 varchar(50))
INSERT INTO ejemplo (columna1,columna2) values ('ejemplo','n1') , ('ejemplo','n1') , ('ejemplo','n2') ,('ejemplo','n2')

select columna1, columna2 from ejemplo
```

ahora bien quiero agrupar tomando en cuenta una sola columna es decir group by columna1, de esta manera obtengo dos líneas, se que la manera correcta es en group se mencione las dos columnas pero en este caso quiero nombrar solo una columna.

Comment: y entonces no agregues la segunda columna a la consulta.. o agregala despues del group by....

Comment: es necesario nombrar las dos columnas, y luego ejecutar el group nombrando solo una. repito, es un ejemplo sencillo para darme a entender.

Comment: no. no es un ejemplo sencillo... no te estas dando a entender. Con este ejemplo, la respuesta es, hace el group by con una sola, y usa es consulta como el from de otra para agregar lo que falta...

Comment: no se pueden poner menos columnas en el group by, por esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select

Comment: ah vos no queres agrupar, queres un distinct!!!! averigua sobre eso....

Comment: @PedroCastillo, si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Sino quieres usar la **cláusula Group by** puedes usar el **predicado Distinct**.

**Distinct** se usa para omitir los registros que contienen datos duplicados en los campos seleccionados. Para poder ser incluido en los resultados de la consulta, los valores de cada campo enumerado en la instrucción **SELECT** deben ser únicos.

```
select distinct columna1, columna2
from ejemplo
```

Aquí se eliminan los duplicados teniendo en cuenta las dos columnas que pones en el **select**.

**Referencia:** https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/predicados-all-distinct-distinctrow-o-top-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57

Comment: Ojo porque dependiendo la base de datos, distinct puede funcionar un poco diferente... tu referencia es solo para access..