# Agrupar por columna y mostrar la fecha maxima, Mysql GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes comunidad tengo al siguiente consulta

```
SELECT pa.created_at ,pa.dia,pa.direccion_original,pa.identificacion FROM pactados pa
    inner JOIN users u ON u.id = pa.id_usuario
    INNER JOIN localities l ON l.id = pa.id_localidad
    INNER JOIN province pr ON pr.id = id_provincia
    INNER JOIN country co ON co.id = pa.id_pais
    inner JOIN id_pactados i ON i.id_pactado = pa.id 
    INNER JOIN equipos e ON e.id = i.id_equipo
    WHERE pa.id_usuario = '1125' AND pa.estado = 'pactado'
    AND tipo_pactado = 'visita'
    AND 
            pa.dia = '2021-09-07' 
      GROUP BY pa.id 
      ORDER BY pa.created_at desc
```

Estoy queriendo agrupar por direccion_original, pero al hacerlo, no toma
la fecha mas reciente, si no la vieja. He intentado haciendo una subconsulta pero no
arroja el resultado esperado.
Como podria lograr ese resultado agrupando por direccion, y la mayor fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select) y de paso tambien, yo ahi no veo nada que necesite una agrupacion....

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT MAX(pa.created_at) AS created_at ...`

Comment: direccion_original, hay dos direcciones.