# Consulta SQL no me arroja datos correctos

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Estoy realizando una consulta en mi base de datos, pero resulta que necesito saber el saldo unos productos, este es el query que estoy usando:

SELECT motonaves.nombre, items.nombre, items.sae, SUM(inventarios.kilos) - SUM(nacionalizacion.kiloNac)
FROM items
INNER JOIN inventarios ON items.codigoItem = inventarios.codigoMPA
INNER JOIN motonaves ON inventarios.codigoMotonave = motonaves.codigoMotonave
LEFT JOIN nacionalizacion ON inventarios.codigoInventario = nacionalizacion.codigoInventario
GROUP BY items.codigoItem

pero me esta mostrando los siguientes valores:
[image: Resultado del select]

y me debería mostrar para cada registro en el total 35000 y 20000 respectivamente, pero me esta sumando todos los valores, esta es info que tengo en las tablas inventarios y nacionalizacion:
[image: Inventarios]

[image: nacionalizacion]

Como pueden observar no me esta arrojando los valores en el total como son, me esta sumando tanto lo que tengo en nacionliazacion como en inventarios y me aparece un total de 85000.

No se que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: lectura super pero super obligatoria antes de contestar esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select/243359#243359 .... ademas, tu query tiene mal los joins....

Comment: Es por ahi.. y fijate de actualizar la pregunta y cuando estes trabado la resolvemos... pero cuando empieces a ver eso vas a hacer una pregunta mas puntual y mas facil de resolver...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, ya estoy usando los join tal como me aconsejaste, pero mira ahora me salen los resultados pero me esta sumando los resultados de las dos tablas que consulto y me da un total de 85000 cuando me debería mostrar 35000 y 20000 en el otro, agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedas dar

Comment: y ahora, arregla el group by...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, listo ya arregle el group by, pero ahora tengo otro problema me esta sumando doble en la tabla de inventarios, debido a que en nacionalizacion tengo dos entradas de un mismo item de inventario, como lo puedo solucionar???

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, listo por fin pude lograr lo que quería, gracias por por la ayuda